# C pointers and addresses

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I always thought that *&p = p = &*p in C. I tried this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 char a[] = "programming";
 char *ap = &a[4];  

int main(void)
{

 printf("%x %x %x\n", ap, &*(ap), *&(ap));   /* line 13 */
 printf("%x %x %x\n\n", ap+1, &*(ap+1), *&(ap+1));   /* line 14 */
}
```

The first printf line (line 13) gives me the addresses:

40b0a8 40b0a8 40b0a8

which are the same as expected. But when I added the second printf line, Borland complains:

"first.c": E2027 Must take address of a memory location in function main at line 14

I was expecting to get:

40b0a9 40b0a9 40b0a9.

It seems that the expression *&(ap+1) on line 14 is the culprit here. I thought all three pointer expressions on line 14 are equivalent. Why am I thinking wrong?

A second related question: The line

```
char *ap = a;
```

points to the first element of array a. I used

```
char *ap = &a[4];
```

to point to the 5th element of array a.

Is the expression

```
char *ap = a;
```

same as the expression

```
char *ap = &a[0];
```

Is the last expression only more verbose than the previous one?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: To answer your second question: The value of the array name is a pointer to the zeroeth element of that array, thus a would be equivalent to &a[0];

Comment: Thanks. Yes we always point to the zeroeth element. But in C an index can be negative also and C won't complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the C reference operator, it has to point to a valid lvalue, not an arbitrary expression.  Thus, `&(ap+1)` isn't valid because the value `ap+1` is simply an expression, not a location.  You can't say `ap+1 = foo();`

And yes, a is the same as &a[0] here.  Note that *(a+b) is 100% equivalent to a[b] (see the top answer to [Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) for an unusual example of this equivalence).  When getting a pointer to a member of an array, you can use &array[i] or array + i.  Example:

```
struct foo array[5];
struct foo *item_3 = &array[3];
struct foo *also_item_3 = array + 3;
```

In this case, whether to use `array+i` or `&array[i]` is a matter of style.  `&array[i]` is arguably a better choice, as it is clearer that an array item is being gotten.  Moreover, &vec[i] works with C++'s vectors, whereas vec+i does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can we say &array[i] = array + i = &array[0] + i ?

Comment: Yes, because &array[0] is the same as array (provided array is a pointer or array).

Comment: Funny constructions/relationships. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone does not know, lvalue means a value which can be assigned to, so can be on the Left side of the = operator

Answer (score 6):

You can only take the address of an *lvalue*, i.e. an expression that refers to an object. `ap + 1` is an address calculation. It has a value but it's a temporary object so isn't an *lvalue* and you can't take its address.

In answer to your second question, in most contexts in expressions an array decays to a pointer to it's first element so yes, `char *ap = a;` and `char *ap = &a[0];` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I've heard about lvalues and rvalues. I'll need to study them.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe one of those statements is the culprit specifically, I would break that line into three separate lines and see where the compiler complains at you.  I bear the same suspicion, but to confirm it I would do just as I just told you to do.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's the *&(ap+1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Charles is correct about your main question, and you are correct about the second question: `char *ap = a;` is equivalent to `char *ap = &a[0];`.