# Why is JavaScript's regular expression literal syntax considered a design error?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's wrong with JavaScript's regular expression notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078418/whats-wrong-with-javascripts-regular-expression-notation)

[Crockford says](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html)...

> Semicolon insertion was a huge mistake, **as was the notation for literal regular expressions**.

What is the design error with the literal regular expressions? The only one I can think of is that some IDEs don't parse the syntax correctly.