# Java question about autoboxing and object equality / identity

Tags: java, integer, autoboxing

```
public class Main { 
    /** 
      * @param args the command line arguments */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // TODO code application logic here
        int a1 = 1000, a2 = 1000; 
        System.out.println(a1==a2);//=>true 
        Integer b1 = 1000, b2 = 1000;
        System.out.println(b1 == b2);//=>false 
        Integer c1 = 100, c2 = 100; 
        System.out.println(c1 == c2);//=>true 
    }

}
```

Why is `b1 == b2` false and `c1 == c2` true?

Answer (score 39):

Read [this](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42276).

Java uses a **pool** for `Integer`s in the range from -128 to 127.

That means if you create an `Integer` with `Integer i = 42;` and its value is between -128 and 128, **no** new object is created but the corresponding one from the pool is returned. That is why  `c1` is indeed *identical* to `c2`.

(*I assume you know that `==` compares references, not values, when applied to objects*).

Comment: thank Felix Kling very much . I understood this code

Comment: That doesn't explain why a1==a2.

Comment: The question was about `b1==b2` and `c1==c2`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: a1==a2 because they are primitive "int" types, not the Integer object type

Comment: The range is between - 128 and 127.

Answer (score 13):

The correct answers have already been given. But just to add my two cents:

```
Integer b1 = 1000, b2 = 1000;
```

This is awful code. Objects should be initialized as Objects through constructors or factory methods. E.g.

```
 // let java decide if a new object must be created or one is taken from the pool
Integer b1 = Integer.valueOf(1000);
```

or

```
 // always use a new object
 Integer b2 = new Integer(1000);
```

This code

```
Integer b1 = 1000, b2 = 1000;
```

on the other hand implies that Integer was a primitive, which it is not. Actually what you are seeing is a shortcut for

```
Integer b1 = Integer.valueOf(1000), b2 = Integer.valueOf(1000);
```

and Integer only pools objects from -127 to 127, so it will create two new Objects in this case. So although 1000 = 1000, b1 != b2. This is the main reason why I hate auto-boxing.

Comment: `>This is awful code. Objects should be initialized as Objects through constructors or factory methods.`

That's not entirely true. When you're creating instance of the String the best practice is to write `String str = "str";`

Comment: @Rob true that. Also, this answer is very old, not sure I'd write the same today

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer here:

[Strangest language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature) in the 6th answer.

Edit: sorry not exatly the answer. The point is that == compares references, not values when you use it with Integer. But with int "==" means equals.

Answer (score 2):

Because Integer is for a few low numbers like enumeration so there is always same instance. But higher numbers creates new instances of Integer and operator == compares their references

Answer (score 2):

```
  public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
      final int offset = 128;
      if (i >= -128 && i <= 127) { // must cache
          return IntegerCache.cache[i + offset];
      }
       return new Integer(i);
    }
```

Because of this you true in one case, and false in other!

Comment: +1 for this quote from sources. Also the first answer with correct range!

Answer (score 0):

The answer you want is [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=221)

Answer (score 0):

If autounboxing had worked also when doing equality checking with the '==' operator you could write:

```
    Long notNullSafeLong1 = new Long(11L)
    Long notNullSafeLong2 = new Long(22L)
    if ( notNullSafeLong1 == notNullSafeLong2) {
      do suff
```

This would require implementing an override for == so that null==someLong is false and the special case Null==Null is true. Instead we have to use equal() and test for null

```
    Long notNullSafeLong1 = new Long(11L)
    Long notNullSafeLong2 = new Long(22L)
    if ( (notNullSafeLong1 == null && notNullSafeLong2 == null) || 
      (notNullSafeLong1 != null && notNullSafeLong2 != null & 
        notNullSafeLong1.equals(notNullSafeLong2)) {
      do suff
```

This is alittle more verbose than the first example - if autounboxing had worked for the '==' operator.