# Comparing 2 Integer values are giving different output

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java question about autoboxing and object equality / identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351837/java-question-about-autoboxing-and-object-equality-identity)

```
Integer i1 = 10;
Integer i2 = 10;
Integer i3 = 210;
Integer i4 = 210;

if(i1 ==i2){
      System.out.println("True");
}else{
      System.out.println("False");
}
if(i3==i4){
       System.out.println("True");
}else{
       System.out.println("False");
}
if(Integer.valueOf(10) ==Integer.valueOf(10)){
       System.out.println("True");
}else{
      System.out.println("False");
}
if(Integer.valueOf(210) ==Integer.valueOf(210)){
       System.out.println("True");
}else{
       System.out.println("False");
}
```

The answer is

True

False

True

False

Why it is giving false for 2 and 4 condition ?

Comment: You can see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223555/java-comparison-not-working-when-integer-larger-than-128

Comment: Actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117132/integer-wrapper-objects-share-the-same-instances-only-within-the-value-127 is probably the better close target.

Comment: Its an Object, but not as we know it

Comment: In JDK1.5 there is a new concept called Caching Integer Objects.

In JDK1.5 the JVM caches Integer objects from range of -128 to 127 . So every time an integer object is create with value between the above mentioned range same object will be returned instead of creating the new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Integer` is an object, not a primitive. You're comparing different object *instances*.

For this particular example, it's worth reading about [boxing](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/intvsinteger.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use `.equals() to compares Integer`.`==` compares refrences equality

Answer (score 3):

`==` compares instances not values. Use `int` instead of `Integer` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

In Java use the Object function Object.equals(Object) to compare objects. That comparison would only work correctly using the primitive int.