# Java object reusability

Tags: java, performance

```
class MyNetPack {
    Long count;

    public MyNetPack() {
        count = Long.valueOf(0);
    }

    public void reinit(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void process() {
        /* Some calculation */
    }
}

public class MyWork {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyNetPack my = new MyNetPack();
        for (long i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
            my.reinit(i);
            my.process();
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm creating single object by using**

```
MyNetPack my=new MyNetPack();
```

**Afterwards reusing the same object with the reinit method as follows,**

```
for (long i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
    my.reinit(i);
    my.process();
}
```

**Please explain the initial memory allocation & reuse of memory in stack and heap level.**

From my understanding,

MyNetPack reference holder will be allocated in stack and Object will be allocated in heap (with reference holder for count) . Each time in the for loop, The actual value of count (say 1,2,3..) will be allocated newly in heap and the reference will be placed in MyNetPack->count reference holder.

Guide me to minimize new object & memory allocation..

Thanks
Joseph

Comment: I don't think it would reserve new space for each number through the iteration of the loop, it would simply change the value that is already in the reserved heap memory.

Comment: It would be more or less true for reference types but since `long` is a primitive type, this isn't the case.

Comment: I want to reduce the GC as much as possible...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the amount of garbage that this application creates, use `long` instead of `Long` in the `MyNetPack` class.

While the autoboxing `long` to `Long` may reuse existing `Long` objects, it won't do this for large integer values.

(Incidentally, in your example you never actually autobox any `long` value more than once.  This means that the `Long` cache doesn't actually save any memory or reduce the number of allocations.  If anything, it increases both your application's memory usage, and the number of allocations.)

---

On the other hand, you may have a sound reason to use `Long` instead of `long`.  In that case, you will be pleased to know that the JVM's memory management is tuned so that the overheads of allocating and garbage collecting a short-lived object are small.  The overheads are typically smaller than `malloc` / `free` in C or `new` / `dispose` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Since `long` is a primitive type, the field `count` contains the number itself and not a reference to the number.

Therefore there won't be any extra heap allocation at each iteration.

**Update:** I've just seen the catch, the field is of type `Long`. In that case, the number will indeed be autoboxed into a newly created object, except if the number is <=128, in which case you'll always get [the same reference from a pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351837/java-question-about-autoboxing-and-object-equality-identity).

As Stephen says, the solution is not to use `Long` but use the primitive `long`. My rule of thumb is never to use the wrapping classes of primitive types (`Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double` etc.) unless I explicitly need a null-able field. As far as I can tell, that's the only valid reason to use them.

So for example if you have something like this:

```
public class Foo {
  private Long bar;

  public void setBar( long bar ) {
    this.bar = bar; // Autoboxing (and object allocation takes places here!!
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    if (bar == null) { //if the type of bar was long, its uninitialised value would be 0 but what if 0 is a valid value?
      throw new IllegalStateException( "bar not initialised" );
    //...do stuff here with bar, safe in the knowledge that it had been set to a meaningful value
  }
}
```

(Note that this is just an example, I wouldn't recommend it as a design pattern.)

Comment: Thanks bizclop, is there any way to avoid new obeject creation (for >128)?

Comment: I want to reduce the GC as much as possible... Any one can help?

Comment: @user2170066 Why then do you use `Long`?

Comment: If `null` is not legal in any operation then it should be prohibited ASAP, i.e., in the setter. The next step is to use primitive `long` instead and drop the check.

Comment: @maaartinus As you can see, it is prohibited in the setter. But it's still fairly poor design because `doStuff()` only works if you call `setBar()` before it. Which is why I added the disclaimer to the end: it's just a quick and short example of why you would use the wrapping classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
my.reinit(i);
```

yes, every time you will get new object in heap. Autoboxing and Unboxing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html