# Why string string is allowed and int int is not allowed by Compiler?

Tags: c++, types

I am just trying to check whether compiler allows type name as variable name.
When i tried

```
int int;
```

It reported an error saying

> error C2632: 'int' followed by 'int'     is illegal

But when i tried

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string string;
}
```

It didn't give any error.
Both `string` and `int` are data types.

Why compiler allows `string` and doesn't allow `int` ?

EDIT: includes updated.

EDIT: Some people are saying that int is not a class.
In that case, why below line is allowed.

```
int a(10);
```

it works similar to constructor of a class.

Comment: what are your includes ?

Comment: I'll let people with more experience with the standard answer this one, but essentially, `int` is a keyword, while `string` is a class.

Comment: Unfortunately, as this is homework, I don't see how I can help without giving the answer. That said, I think any instructor who would assign a problem like this needs to learn a lesson about reasonable problems for those of us who are not language lawyers.

Comment: Naming a string variable `string` is such a horrible idea.

Comment: `int a(10);` is **initialization** which is equivalent to `int a = 10;`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`string` is not a [`C++ reserved word`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/start), but `int` is, and a reserved word cannot be used as an identifier.

And its **syntactically** fine to have class name and object name to be same.

```
class test {}; 
int main() { 
        test test; // test is an object of type test.
}
```

Comment: Note: Perfectly fine, but any maintainer is going to **kill** you if you do this in real code ;) +1

Comment: This answer is correct, but I take issue with "its fine to have class name and object name to be same".  The Standard may allow it, but it is very much not "fine."

Comment: It's even allowed to say `class test {}; test test;` in C++.

Comment: I disagree John.  In most cases, yes, I would avoid it.  But how about Color color?  Stuff like that makes sense sometimes, nothing is absolute.

Comment: "class test {} test;" is also allowed

Comment: Even worse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2000491#2000491

Comment: @Ed: `Color color;` is fine, since the cases are different. There is no excuse for `Color Color;` though. If you _must_ use the same name as the class, just use static variables/constants, i.e., `Color::BLUE`.

Answer (score 6):

`int` is a C++ keyword. In the second declaration 'string string' declares an object of type `'std::string'`. After this the name 'string' hides `'std::string'` in an unqualified lookup

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main(){
    string string;

    string s;  // Error
}
```

Comment: Note that the the first use (`string string`) is only valid if `<string>` is `#include` 'd and `using namespace std;` is present in the file.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Or `using std::string` :)

Answer (score 3):

`int` is a keyword, whereas `string` is the name of a class in the standard library but is not a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`string` isn't actually a "data type" in the same sense the `int` is.   `int` is a "native type" and as such, the text "int" is a keyword.

`string` is just a "user-defined" class  (although, here the "user" the defined it is the C++ standards committtee).  But as such, "string" is *not* a keyword.

So `int int` is two keywords together, but `string string` is just defining a varaible named "string" of type "string".  The C++ compiler can keeps the separate two uses of "string" straight (but it's not a good idea to do this, since, as you've demonstrated, programmers often can't).

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that others have essentially posted the answer, I'm going to go ahead and post what I meant...

I'm assuming that because the second answer compiles, that you have `using namespace std;` in your file (which is in general not a good idea; I fail to see why people tell beginning C++ users to do this).

When the compiler goes to resolve the first `string`, it is able to find the class in namespace `std`. The second use of `string` is simply the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler allows primitive types to behave like classes for the purposes of templates - if you had to specialize for primitives everywhere it would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
#include <string>
```