# When is the `==` operator not equivalent to the `is` operator? (Python)

Tags: python, comparison, equality

I noticed I can use the `==` operator to compare all the native data types (integers, strings, booleans, floating point numbers etc) and also lists, tuples, sets and dictionaries which contain native data types. In these cases the `==` operator checks if two objects are equal. But in some other cases (trying to compare instances of classes I created) the `==` operator just checks if the two variables reference the same object (so in these cases the `==` operator is equivalent to the `is` operator)

**My question is: When does the `==` operator do more than just comparing identities?**

EDIT: I'm using Python 3

Comment: Essentially, `==` is different from `is`, whenever a class overrides the `__eq__` method it inherits from `object`, so there is no easy answer to this question. Depending on the Python version you are using, things get even more complicated due to the existence of `__cmp__`. Besides curiosity, is there a practical reason for the question?

Comment: @Dirk, thanks. I'm asking it mostly out of curiosity, but I also think it's good to know when exactly I can use the == operator to check object equality.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python, the `==` operator is implemented in terms of the [magic method `__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization), which by default implements it by identity comparison. You can, however, override the method in order to provide your own concept of object equality. Note, that if you do so, you will usually also override at least `__ne__` (which implements the `!=` operator) and `__hash__`, which computes a hash code for the instance.

I found it very helpful, even in Python, to make my `__eq__` implementations comply with the rules set out in the Java language for implementations of the [`equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, namely:

- It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
- It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
- It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
- It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
- For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

the last one should probably replace `null` with `None`, but the rules are not as easy here in Python as in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the rule set for implementing '__eq__'

Comment: This "rules" have strong mathematical root: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation

Comment: tell that to javascript ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224

Comment: I would add that \__eq\__ in python has a notably different behavior from Java by allowing \__eq\__ to raise NotImplemented, which defers the check for equality to the other class. This blog post is quite helpful: http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/32837.html. This allows you to satisfy the symmetric requirement even when dealing with inheritance. If Java allowed this feature, I believe that the Numbers class could implement Comparable by allowing child classes to determine equality.

Comment: Note that you do **not** have to implement the `__ne__` magic method when you implement `__eq__`: by default testing for `a != b` will return `not (a == b)`.

Answer (score 18):

`==` and `is` are always conceptually distinct: the former delegates to the left-hand object's `__eq__` [1], the latter always checks identity, without any delegation.  What seems to be confusing you is that `object.__eq__` (which gets inherited by default by user-coded classes that don't override it, of course!) is implemented in terms of identity (after all, a bare `object` has absolutely **nothing** to check **except** its identity, so what else could it possibly do?!-).

[1] omitting for simplicity the legacy concept of the `__cmp__` method, which is just a marginal complication and changes nothing important in the paragraph's gist;-).

Answer (score 7):

The `==` does more than comparing identity when ints are involved. It doesn't just check that the two ints are the same object; it actually ensures their values match. Consider:

```
>>> x=10000
>>> y=10000
>>> x==y,x is y
(True, False)
>>> del x
>>> del y
>>> x=10000
>>> y=x
>>> x==y,x is y
(True, True)
```

The "standard" Python implementation does some stuff behind the scenes for small ints, so when testing with small values you may get something different. Compare this to the equivalent `10000` case:

```
>>> del y
>>> del x
>>> x=1
>>> y=1
>>> x==y,x is y
(True, True)
```

Answer (score 4):

What is maybe most important point is that recommendation is to always use:

```
if myvalue is None:
```

not

```
if myvalue == None:
```

And never to use:

```
if myvalue is True:
```

but use:

```
if myvalue:
```

This later point is not so supper clear to me as I think there is times to separate the boolean True from other True values like "Alex Martelli" , say there is not False in "Alex Martelli" (absolutely not, it even raises exception :) ) but there is '' in "Alex Martelli" (as is in any other string).

Comment: What makes 'if myvalue is None' better than 'if myvalue == None'?

Comment: See PEP8 for the rule. See Alex' comments about __eq__, additionally it is faster: http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html