# Python is vs ==

Tags: python, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs)
>   [When is the `==` operator not equivalent to the `is` operator? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647692/when-is-the-operator-not-equivalent-to-the-is-operator-python)

I'm pretty new to Python still. I heard someone say use `is`, not `==` because "this isn't C". But I had some code `x is 5` and it was not working as expected.

So, following proper Python/PEP style, when is the time to use `is` and when is the time to use `==` ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why) for an explanation of `is` vs `==`

Comment: Lots of great links. The only time you naively want to use `is` is for testing None. Otherwise default to `==`

Comment: Whoever you heard saying "use `is`, not `==`" is flat wrong and you should take any other advice they give with a grain of salt. You almost never need to use `is` in Python.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I saw it on a comment on some SO question I was reading a couple days ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use `==` to compare two values. You should use `is` to see if two names are bound to the same object.

You should almost never use `x is 5` because depending on the implementation small integers might be interned. This can lead to surprising results:

```
>>> x = 256
>>> x is 256
True
>>> x = 257
>>> x is 257
False
```

Comment: When I do the second assignment and second `is` check, it still returns True. I'm using Python 2.7. EDIT: Actually, I used 1 and 2 for the first/second values, but then tried 256/257 and got the same results you listed. What's going on here?

Comment: @Manny D: In the Python implementation you are using, numbers that are 256 or less are interned for efficiency. Every time you write 256 you get the *exact* same object. Each time you write 257, you get a new, different object but with the same value of course. But you shouldn't rely on this behaviour because it may change in future versions.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be two more different objects that compared as equal values. Say `1` and `1.0`. This example is a bit esoteric when there are more obvious mainstream ones at hand.

Comment: @MannyD You can also get this odd behavior with short strings, as they can be interned as well. You'll also get it with singletons like `True`, `False`, and `None`.

Answer (score 2):

The two operators have different meaning.

- `is` tests object identity. Do the two operands refer to the same object?
- `==` tests equality of value. Do the two operands have the same value?

When it comes to comparing `x` and `5` you invariably are interested in the value rather than the object holding the value.