# `is` in python after split gives True with single digit and False for double digits

Tags: python, string, comparison, string-comparison

Please do not mark duplicated YET.
I did read this [Python is vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718790/python-is-vs)

I have read around and noticed `==` vs `is` that `is` checks if same memory location and `==` is used to compare two values but recently I was using `is` by accident BUT to me it's acting weird and I am don't really understand why though.

I am trying to parse a url path to see if the page number matches for example

```
a = '9'
b = '/category-1-11-9.html'
c = b.split('.html')[0].split('-')[-1]
print(a is c, ' bool')  # this gives True


a = '10'
b = '/category-1-11-10.html'
c = b.split('.html')[0].split('-')[-1]
print(a is c, ' bool')  # this gives False
```

I figured if the number is a single digit, I get `True` as return and if number is 10 or more I get `False`

I tried to `print` both `a` and `c` to see their `type` and `value`, ended up both type`and`value` are the same.  But why with a single digit it gives True and double digits it gives False?

I am quite confused with this even after reading articles about `is`

Using python version 3.7.7

Comment: TL;DR: never use `is` where you mean to use `==`. Only ever expect `is` to return any particular result if you're testing objects you have personally assigned to another variable (e.g. `a = b; assert a is b`). In any other situation, you want to test for *equality*, not *identity*.

Comment: In how far do you consider this weird? Python makes no guarantees about the uniqueness of its builtin immutable types – the same value *may* be always the same object, just as it *may* be not. *Why* did you expect a different behaviour?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks for that explanation, I get what you mean now

Comment: From Mark Byers response in the link you reference: _You should use `==` to compare two values. You should use `is` to see if two names are bound to the same object_. Python implementations have objects for common items, such as small integers and perhaps (as in your example) individual character strings, so whilst these _may_ point to the same object, you can't rely on that behaviour except for testing against `None`, `True` or `False`