# How did a float turn into a double here?

Tags: java, numbers

Edit: As always, great answer in under 5 minutes :) Turns out if I make a tiny change - make the F capital in "float", I'll get the output I expected.

```
class NumberMachine{
      public static void main(String [] args) {
        Integer wi1 = new Integer("420");
        int i = 101;
        Integer wi2 = i*420/101;
        if(wi1 == wi2) System.out.print(" =="); 
        if(wi1.equals(wi2)) System.out.print(" equal"); 
         float f = 1.23f; //if this were Float f..., it'd print Float, not double.
         new NumberMachine().printIt(f);
      }

      void printIt(Float f){
         System.out.println(" Float");
      }
      void printIt(double  d){
         System.out.println(" double");
      }
  }
```

The output is  `equal double`, which makes no sense to me. I expected  `equal Float`. If I comment out the 2nd printIt, then that's indeed the output. I just don't know why, when faced with a choice between the two printIt, the compiler ignored the one whose parameter matched perfectly.

Comment: You've got lower case "f" `float` the body of the code but upper case "F" `Float` in the method arguments. It's been a while since I did Java (15 years) but are they different types/classes?

Comment: Yep. Float is a class, and float is a primitive type. Apparently Java 5 makes it easy to interchange them, but it also sneakily converts floats to doubles - hence the output.

Comment: A comment not related to your question: I noticed that you use "==" to compare wi1 and wi2. Remember that if you want to compare two Integer instances you should use the `equals` method. Using "==" can lead to weird results (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2001861#2001861 )

Comment: This isn't my code. It's the source code from an exam, and I just copypasted it. The == was part of the trick - to see if I knew that it's not the same as equals :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the result you do because boxing/unboxing was added late in Java's life and it was required that pre-existing code not be changed by the addition of the feature. So when you pass in a primitive float to printIt, it gets coerced to a primitive double, because the alternative would mean old (pre-JDK1.4) code would act differently, which was an unacceptable possibility for Sun.

Basically, think if this was pre-JDK1.4 code where boxing was not an alternative, no way could the primitive double get coerced to a java.lang.Float. Adding boxing can't be allowed to break that.

Reading the question it occurs to me from how you word it you may not see the difference between Float and float, because you refer to the change from capital F to lowercase F as a tiny change, when it really isn't so tiny. The lowercase version refers to a primitive numeric type, the uppercase version refers to an object that wraps the primitive numeric type, in order to allow numeric stuff to be used in general purpose things like collections. Prior to JDK1.4 if you wanted to do something like this you had to manually write a line like

```
myList.add(new Float(1.0F));
```

if you wanted to add a float value to a list. The addition of boxing/unboxing in JDK1.4 tried to paper over this and have the compiler do this for us, but unfortunately you still have to understand the difference between the two to make sense of what's going on.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'll just add that if you make both printIt methods take a wrapper type (change printIt(double d) to printIt(Double d)) or make both take a primitive type (float and double, rather than Float and Double), then what you expect will happen.  Using Float and Double outside of generics is generally a mistake.

Comment: I meant typographically tiny :) But yeah, I do get the distinction, as mentioned in the comment under the original post.

Comment: @RickyClarkson Also, when the domain logic explicitly allows `null` values, e.g. in entities mapped to database tables with Hibernate, then it is a valid use-case to define properties as boxed types. Code which accesses such properties should always handle the possibility of nulls then though, which is a major PITA indeed.

Comment: I'd rather use Option<Double> and stick to my 'no null' rule.  May it forever serve me well.