# Java: why the "long" primitive type does not accept a simple number?

Tags: java, casting, int, long-integer, primitive-types

I got a method that receives a `long` type parameher, and I try to call it passing `1`:

```
contato.setId(1);
```

And I receive this:

```
The method setId(Long) in the type Contato is not applicable for the arguments (int).
```

But, isn't `1` a long number as well? Isn't it inside the long **scope**??

PS: Just to say, I solved the problem with this code:

```
Integer y = 1;
long x = y.longValue();
contato.setId(x);
```

It's just a didatic question.

Comment: If the method accepted a little-l `long`, it'd work just fine; it's just that int literals can't autobox directly to `Long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did a float turn into a double here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3680879/217324) - my answer there explains the decisions behind the autoboxing limitation mentioned in Louis' comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long` is a datatype that contains 64bits (not to be confused with the Object `Long`!) vs. an int (32 bits), so you can't use a simple assignment from `int` to `long`. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

In order to see how to declare the various datatypes, you should check specifically the [following table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#h1):

```
Datatype    Default Value
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0L
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char        '\u0000'
Object      null
boolean     false
```

So, for your case, `long` should be declared with the number followed by an `L`, for instance:

```
long x = 100L;
```

Further, doing what you're doing with [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

```
Integer y = 1;
long x = y.longValue();
```

is not only unnecessary - it's very wasteful as well. So, for example, if you'll do it in a loop (many times) your code will be slower in order of magnitude!

Answer (score 7):

You should use `contato.setId(1L);` (notice the "L" suffix)

The literal "1" represents a primitive `int` value, which is casted to an `java.lang.Integer` wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

`Long` is not a primitive type, `long` is. When using the wrapper classes instead of the primitive types, you need to explicitly indicate to the compiler that the passed argument is a `long` by adding the `L` suffix:

```
contato.setId(1L);
```

Or you can simply change the `setId` method so that it takes a primitive `long` argument instead.

Comment: There is also a possibility that the capital "L" on the setId argument type is a typo, and the correct fix is to make it take a primitive `long`.

Answer (score 0):

`setId` takes a capital-L `Long`, which is Java's wrapper around lowercase-l `long` (AKA 64-bit integer). Because of this, Java easily knows how to convert a `long` to a `Long` without you doing anything special. So, like the other answers say, you could simply do `setId(1L)`, which is giving it a `long`, which it easily converts to a `Long`.

However, if you must use a 32-bit `int`, you must first convert it to a `long` or a `Long`, so Java knows how to handle it. You see, Java does not know implicitly how to convert a lowercase-i `int` to an uppercase-L `Long`, only to an uppercase-I `Integer` (the wrapper class around `int`).

So, assuming your int's name is `i`, you can use these as well:

```
setId((long)i);         // Cast your int to a long, which Java can turn into a Long
setId((Long)(long)i);   // Cast your int to a long, then that long to a Long
setId(new Long(i));     // Create a new Long object based on your int
setId(Long.valueOf(i)); // Get the Long version of your int
```