# Double instance variables in java

Tags: java

Why do double instance variables in java have a lower case d attached to them? Do they need to have this?

Example:

```
double area = 0d;
double avgDailyTemp = 26d;
```

etc...

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28353219/1057429 it talks about `long` but provides information about `double` as well

Comment: Can you reword your question, because its unclear. whats a double instance variable? double is primitive and not an object, primitives are lower cased in Java

Comment: @SleimanJneidi OP is asking if `d` part in `26d` is mandatory for `double`.

Comment: I see, it doesn't need to be lower case, 26D works as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number literal by default is an integer. If you attempt to pass a number like ten billion into Java double it'll error since it's outside the bounds of an integer. Specifying the lowercase `d` explicitly defines it as a double literal instead.

Comment: You can also add a "." at the end instead of d: `double area = 260000000000.;`

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = 10000000000; // ERROR! Integer number too large 
double b = 10000000000d; // OK!
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `d` the numbers 0 and 26 are `int` values.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the variable which requires the `d`, but the constant value declared. It is a "hint" to the compiler of the data type.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html