# Why don't number literals have access to Number methods?

Tags: javascript

If you look at the ECMAScript 3 specification you will see that primitive value types Null and Undefined don't have accompanying Null and Undefined Objects.

```
>> Null
ReferenceError: Null is not defined
```

The other primitive value types Number, String and Boolean types do have accompanying Number, String and Boolean objects which you can reference from global scope.

```
>>Number
function Number() { [native code] }
>>Boolean
function Boolean() { [native code] }
```

The purpose for these primitive value types is to provide methods such as `toString` and `valueOf` for their respective primitive value types:

```
>>var n = 1;
>>n.toString();
"1"
```

is the same as

```
>>var n = 1;
>>Number.prototype.toString.call(n);
"1"
```

Booleans and strings also work that way:

```
>>var b = true;
>>b.toString(); 
"true"
>>Boolean.prototype.toString.call(b);
"true"
```

You can see that the primitive value objects are using the methods of their accompanying object when you try to mix types:

```
>>Boolean.prototype.toString.call(n); 
TypeError: Boolean.prototype.toString is not generic
>>Number.prototype.toString.call(b)
TypeError: Number.prototype.toString is not generic
```

Interestingly enough for boolean and string literal types, you can call these methods directly from the literal:

```
>>true.toString();
"true"
>>Boolean.prototype.toString.call(true)
"true"
>>"moo".toString();
"moo"
>>String.prototype.toString.call("moo")
"moo"
```

Primitive values null and undefined, since they don't have accompanying Null and Undefined objects cannot do these things:

```
>>Null
ReferenceError: Null is not defined
>>null.toString()
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of null
```

Primitive value type number behaves like a mix of the two. You can call `toString` on a literal if you directly use the Number's prototype object's method:

```
>>Number.prototype.toString.call(1);
"1"
```

But you cannot access the method from the literal itself like you can with strings and booleans:

```
>>1.toString()
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Why is it that number literals behave differently from boolean and string even though there's a Number object?

Comment: see also [Why can't I access a property of an integer with a single dot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9380077/1048572)

Comment: Oh, good points. Wasn't sure. That other post had good information. Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You *can* access it the same way, it's a different parsing issue here, to do it, use a slightly different syntax:

```
(1).toString()
```

Numbers can have decimals, so the syntax for ending in a decimal is a bit ambiguous when you go to parse the code, use parenthesis to be valid.  It's a bit clearer when you see that this is also valid:

```
(1.).toString()
```

However with just `1.toString()` it's trying to parse as a number *with a decimal*, and it fails.

Comment: Didn't consider to try it with (). Wish I could mark two answers as answers. So basically the literal has the property, but you just have to deal with the extra decimal syntax. Thanks!

Comment: 1..toFixed(2), 1.0.toFixed(2) work without parens.

Comment: @kennebec - Yes, they'll work as well, I was more conveying that `(anyType).toString()` would be a consistent format that would work, sorry if that wasn't entirely clear...didn't mean to imply there weren't alternatives for numbers specifically.

Answer (score 8):

I think you'll find an answer to your question in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/3297392#3297392) to another Stack Overflow question. To summarize [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109/theo)'s answer:

> [T]he parser expects a number followed
>   by a dot to be a floating point
>   literal. [...] [Y]ou only have to add another dot to make it work[.]

Comment: Wow! I figured it had something to do with the decimal, but I thought there would be more to it. Interesting, see I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score -1):

Null (capital N) is a variable name.  Reserved words are case sensitive. null is the object null.  typeof null === "object" //true

Comment: `null.toString()` --> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null*