# Why are some literals, actually objects, while others are just non-object literals?

Tags: javascript

Assume that I have two literals: `false` and `1`. If I invoke function `toString()` on both of them, I get:

```
false.toString() // false
1.toString()     // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

What does error happen in the second case and does not occur in the first one?

Comment: Put parentheses around the `1`. That should fix the error.

Comment: It is not an option here. If I do that I will invoke function toString on string literal, and not on the number literal.

Comment: No, if you put parentheses around it, it will still be a number. `(1) === 1`. Putting parentheses doesn't change the value of anything; it's just that the JavaScript console thought the `.` was a decimal point, which is why they didn't expect `toString`. However, putting parentheses around the `1` makes the console parse the one as a number before the `.`, so the `.` now looks like a property/method getter instead of a decimal point because the console has finished parsing the number.

Comment: ok, `typeof (1)` gives me a `number`.

Comment: Try `(1).toString()` or `1..toString()`... Both let the parser know that the `.` isn't a decimal point.

Comment: It is some kind of JS trick, right?

Comment: I'm writing an answer to an answer to this question right now, which will hopefully explain things for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't number literals have access to Number methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046342/why-dont-number-literals-have-access-to-number-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, numbers are object literals. It's just that you need to put parentheses around the number so the console finishes parsing the number. This way, the `.` isn't mistaken for a decimal point. You can also put `.`s, one for a decimal point and one for the `.toString()`:

```
//This outputs "2":
console.log((2).toString());
//So does this:
console.log(2..toString());
var hello = 2;
//So does this:
console.log(hello.toString());
```

For more on this parsing error, go check out [@vihan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161552/why-are-some-literals-actually-objects-while-others-are-just-non-object-litera/32161680#32161634).

In JavaScript, there is a prototype for every type. For `true` and `false`, there is the `Boolean` prototype. For numbers like `1`, there is the `Number` prototype. For strings like `"Hi!"`, there is the `String` prototype. However, Booleans, numbers, and strings are all primitive objects, meaning they are immutable, meaning that you can't set properties on them like regular objects:

```
var hello = 2;
//hello is a Number object and can have properties and methods like .toString():
console.log(hello.toString());
//This doesn't work, however, because while hello is an object, it is immutable:
hello.hello = 2;
//This outputs undefined because the above didn't work:
console.log(hello.hello);
```

In contrast, arrays (from the `Array` prototype), functions (from the `Function` prototype), are mutable objects, so you can set properties on them just fine. Also, regular objects like `{regular: true}` descend from the `Object` prototype and are also mutable.

```
var arr = [1, 2];
//arr is mutable, so this works just fine and outputs 2:
arr.hello = 2;
console.log(arr.hello);
```

Thus, all literals in JavaScript are objects, but some are mutable while others are immutable. You can also make regularly mutable objects immutable with [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), but making mutable objects immutable is even more complicated.

It should be noted that *all* of these prototypes -- `Boolean`, `String`, `Number`, `Array`, `Function` -- descend from `Object`. This is because all prototypes are objects themselves and must thus descend from `Object`. This is like how in Java where all classes descend from `Object` somehow. However, there is a way to get rid of descending from `Object` using [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), but that's EVEN MORE CONFUSING and it's probably not good to get into that if you're just getting into JavaScript.

I hope this explanation has helped you understand JavaScript better!

Comment: `prototype` and inheritance have nothing to do with this it's purely semantics.

Comment: His question was about understanding how JavaScript object literal works, not necessarily the parsing error. This gives him a more in-depth understanding of JavaScript objects instead of just telling him how to fix his example.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Perhaps you could add both in your answer? In the future, people who visit this question will have no idea on how his problem was fixed.

Comment: @vihan No problem! Done! I added it at the top.

Comment: *"numbers are object literals"* - Aren't they primitive literals? And then JS coerces them into the equivalent object if you call numeric methods on them.

Comment: Yes, numbers, strings, and Booleans are primitive literals, but all values, including primitives, are objects in JavaScript. However, primitives are immutable and have a secret _[[PrimitiveValue]]_ property storing their value. However, other Web sites (like [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)) will dispute this and say that primitives aren't objects. I think this is a dispute between JavaScript coders, but it remains that primitive values _clearly_ descend from prototypes such as `Number.prototype`, even if you don't wrap them in an "object wrapper."

Answer (score 4):

## Using `..`

Basically, `1` is a number so if it is immediately followed by a decimal it is taken as a floating point literal and expects to be followed by the fractional value (like `1.0`).

`1..toString()` works because `1.` is valid number literal and it knows to treat the next dot to access the object's properties. This means:

```
1.1.toString(); // Works
1.toString();   // "toString()" isn't a number so we get an error
```

---

## Using `[]`

```
var toString = "toString";
```

Now you can do:

```
1[toString]();
```

---

## Using `()`

You can use parenthesis for this. This works in a similar way to declaring a variable:

```
var a = 5;
a.toString();
```

```
(5).toString();
```

Why does this work?

> It's because **only when there is a `.`** It will expect the following to be numbers.

---

## Error

If you type in `1.toString()` on your console (I'm using Safari). It should say:

```
At least one digit must occur after a decimal point
```

meaning it is expecting a digit.

---

## What to do?

Because it can get annoying doing `..` or adding extra parenthesis. You can use the **`String`** function to get around this:

```
String(1);
```