# Why does a method like `toString` require two dots after a number?

Tags: javascript

What is the logic behind `42..toString()` with `..`?

The double dot works and returns the string `"42"`, whereas `42.toString()` with a single dot fails.

Similarly, `42...toString()` with three dots also fails.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

```js
console.log(42..toString());
```

```js
console.log(42.toString());
```

Comment: First dot is considered as decimal point

Comment: This could be interpreted as 42.0 without the trailing 0, then converting the integer to a string.

Comment: then `42.toString()` must work .. considering integer..

Comment: The first dot is a decimal point, the second is the property accessor. This avoids parsing ambiguity between a member: 42.member and a mantissa: 42.123.

Comment: First dot is decimal point and second dot is for actual toString(). The Complier gets confused with single dot.

Comment: Although the question is quite different, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4046367/1220550) explains quite well how to use it and why so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you enter `42.toString()` it will be parsed as 42 with decimal value "toString()" which is of course illegal. `42..toString()` is simply a short version of `42.0.toString()` which is fine. To get the first one to work you can simply put paranthesis around it `(42).toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

it is like 42.0.tostring() so it show's decimal point you can use (42).toString()  42 .toString() that also work there is space between 42 and dot. This is all because in javascript almost everything is object so that confusion in dot opt.

Answer (score 1):

***With just 42.toString(); it's trying to parse as a number with a decimal, and it fails.***

and when we write 42..toString(); taken as 42.0.toString();

we can get correct output by

(42).toString();

(42.).toString();

[Can refer Link for .toString() usage](http://2ality.com/2012/03/converting-to-string.html)