# Why the parentheses around numbers are required to call Number methods

Tags: javascript

The following syntax generates an error:

```
5.toString();
```

But the following doesn't:

```
(5).toString();
```

What does the parentheses exactly do here?

Comment: They clarify that you're not trying to write a float.

Comment: Sheesh.  Javascript is such a weird language.

Comment: you could add another dot: `5..toString();`

Comment: Even weirder. ..

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046342/why-dont-number-literals-have-access-to-number-methods

Comment: @NinaScholz Of course. But why can't we directly call it on the number?

Comment: @CharlieH see the dup.

Comment: @Robert This isn't exactly unique to Javascript…

Comment: First time I've ever seen it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It looks that even `5 .toString()` works!

Comment: the only reason for parentheses is if you use a negative number, then the sign is later applied and the value is now a number again.

Comment: think of the **parens** containing a comma delimited list of expressions where the **value** as a whole is the last one in the list.  Therefore (5).ToString() would be '5'.  (1,2,3) would b e 3.   ('a','b',3+5) would be 8