# I've heard Javascript inserts ";" automatically and that may cause problems

Tags: javascript, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I've also heard that Go insert them too, but they followed a different [approach](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/7facb7856f017791)

How does Javascript insert semicolons while interpreting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the biggest things I've found is, let's say you have a function that returns coordinates (or any object really), similar to this.

```
function getCoordinates() {
    return
        {
            x: 10,
            y: 10
        };
}
```

You would expect to get back an object right?  WRONG!  You get back undefined.  The interpreter converts the code into this

```
function getCoordinates() {
    return;
        {
            x: 10,
            y: 10
        };
}
```

Since `return` by itself is a valid statement.  You need to be sure to write the return as follows

```
function getCoordinates() {
    return {
            x: 10,
            y: 10
        };
}
```

Comment: Yep, I already posted the same thing. ;) Howver, you *don't* get back `null`, you get `undefined`.

Comment: @Guffa, correct.  And corrected.

Comment: Took at least 40 minutes away from my life, so mad now.

Comment: @MészárosLajos, But less than an hour...so, not as bad as most! I'd consider it a win.

Comment: @CaffGeek Ah, an optimist!

Answer (score 4):

Javascript assumes end of statement at any line break where it's possible. For example this:

```
return
true;
```

is interpreted as:

```
return;
true;
```

turning the return and it's argument into two separate statements, which of course means that the function has no return value (returns undefined).

I wrote a [blog entry](http://blog.guffa.com/2010/02/javascript-almost-not-line-based/) about that a while back.

Comment: yep, I just posted the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The example that taught me the pitfalls of this particular feature was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2003277#2003277) in the "Strangest language feature?" question. (Which is why I was for reopening that question, by the way - it is a valuable learning resource.)

Good reference material can be found here: [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion)