# Is there a difference between main(String args[]) and main(String[] args)?

Tags: java, coding-style, argument-passing

Is there a difference between:

```
public void main(String args[]) { ... }
```

and

```
public void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

I don't believe so, but I am wondering.

Comment: As you said, coding style. I know many people prefer the second because it seems clearer that `args` is an array of `String` rather than an array of `args`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Semantically, they are identical. However, I'd recommend using the latter syntax (`String[] args`) when declaring arrays. The former syntax is there mainly for compatibility with C syntax.

Since `String[]`, as a whole, is the type of the object in Java, it's more consistent and clear not to split it up.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699309/weird-after-java-method-signature) addresses the `[]` after method argument list.

Answer (score 9):

There's no difference, but putting the brackets after the type (`String[]`) is the more common practice in Java.

Answer (score 8):

Both of them are absolutely the same. Please refer to Java Language Specification (JLS) to see the syntax used in java.

`String[] args` or `String args[]` will create an array (reserves a place in memory) with no size and name `args`.

Let us Consider:

```
String [] x;
```

Putting the `[]` after the name avoids subtle problems like this:-

```
String x [] , y; //x[] is an array but y is a String
String [] x y ; //two arrays x[] and y[] both
```

Answer (score 4):

Although both are used to create array of String type but second one is more popular, because with that, you can create multiple String arrays simultaneously... E.g `String[] a,b;`
Here you have created two String Arrays a and b simultaneously.

However

`String a[],b;` *will create String array "a" and  String variable(not array) b*.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

**No**

They are just two style of writting

Answer (score 1):

The method signature is the same so there is no difference.

Its a public method, it returns nothing, the method name is "main" and the it takes a String array.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There is no difference b/w the two.

See `Declaring a Variable to Refer to an Array` section in [this doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). From that doc

> float anArrayOfFloats[]; // this form
>   is discouraged

so just use the second style.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these is that when we try to call the main method manually from one class to another by using static syntax , we  use "string[] s ". At that point we have to pass an array of string type as argument in main method. When we are using "String... s" then there is no need to pass any string array as an argument. It will run and it doesn't matter if you pass the array as an argument or not (if you don't explicitly pass it, it is passed by itself)  ...
**hence proved/////////**

Answer (score 0):

Apart from these two styles, it is worth mentioning that the following is also a valid signature for the `main()` method since Java 5:

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

From the [Java Language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of String.

The ellipsis `...` is the syntax for var-args, which can be used to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a method. More on it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs).

Answer (score 0):

String args[] and String[] args are identical. In the sense that they do the same thing, Creating a string array called args.

But to avoid confusion and enforce compatibility with all other Java codes you may encounter I'd recommend using the syntax (String[] args) when declaring arrays.

One confusion you may encounter is when you try to declare multiple String array in one line, then  `String[] fruits, vegetables` will not be the same as `String fruits[], vegetables`

The former creates two string arrays *fruits* and *vegetables*, while the later creates a String array of *fruits* and a string variable of *vegetables*

Answer (score -3):

there is a difference:
For example
if you write int[] arr; - here arr is the reference to the integer array
whereas in case of int arr[]; - arr is a primitive int type array