# Proper way to write Java's main method

Tags: java

I've seen this written two different ways:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Is there a difference here? Which one is preferred? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about: `public static void main(String...args)`

Comment: It's a matter of preference. I personally use `String[]` because it's an array of strings, not an args array.

Comment: Same question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175193/java-array-convention-string-args-vs-string-args)

Comment: I agree with @Jeroen. Put the [] next to what is actually an array. If you were to read it as a sentence: String array for args variable. But that's just person preference.

Comment: If you seek for array declaration in Java, this question would have never arose. Note: check link in @Adarsh comment.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. I prefer String[] because I think the fact that this is an array is part of the type.

Answer (score 2):

No way is "better" than the other, as both are valid java syntaxes. You simply should be consistent, and use the one that makes *most sense to you in the end*. You're doing nothing more than declaring a `String` array called `args` as a parameter. Either is valid for this. I personally prefer `String[] args` but both are technically valid.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. Look at this example from Java Language Specification:

> The [ ] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.

```
byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
```

This declaration is equivalent to:

```
byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
```

Comment: +1: This is the only answer that really explains why both ways are equivalent.