# Differentiate between String args[] and String[] args

Tags: java, string

I have seen two different ways of declaring array of String but I don't undrestand the difference. Can anyone explain what is the difference between

`String args[]`

and

```
String[] args
```

Comment: No difference..

Comment: The former is supported to please former C programmers.

Comment: About the first form, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) says "convention discourages this form"

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175193/java-array-convention-string-args-vs-string-args) question and accepted answer has some more info on the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference (in Java). They're exactly the same thing. From [JLS §10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

Answer (score 2):

**They is no difference** but I prefer the brackets after type - it's easier to see that the variable's type is array and also it's more readable.

But always it depends on developer which approach he'll pick up and it's more comfortable for him to use. See @T.J. Crowder answer that refers to official docs.

Comment: I prefer to follow the Java Coding Conventions, just because they are standard and saves lots of discussion about the various alternatives like space vs tabs etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is if you are declaring a variable and you add more fields.

```
String args[], array[];  // array is String[]

String[] args, array[];  // array is String[][]
```

However, if you refering to your main method I prefer to use

```
public static void main(String... args) {
```

or if the args are ignored

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
```

The `String...` is much the same as `String[]` except it can be called with varargs instead of an array. e.g.

```
MyClass.main("Hello", "World");
```

BTW A good example of why I don't like `[]` after the variable as the type is `String[]` not `String .... ??`

This actually compiles

```
public int method(String args[])[] {
```

which is the same as

```
public int[] method(String[] args) {
```

but I think the later is better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in `String args[]` and `String[] args`.Both ways are same.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference between them. They are both the declaration of an array. To Java compiler, they are same. Just declare an array variable