# How can I tell between a blank textbox and a textbox with zero in it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, null, nan, zero

I have the following:

```
var NewCount = document.getElementById('MainContent_gv_NewCount_' + rowIndex).value;
if (NewCount != "") {
    document.getElementById('MainContent_gv_lblTotal_' + rowIndex).innerHTML = "£" + ((originalCount - NewCount) * unitCost).toFixed(2);
} else { 
   document.getElementById('MainContent_gv_lblTotal_' + rowIndex).innerHTML = "";
            }
```

The calculations I am doing are based on the value in the textbox. (NewCount).

I want the label to update if the value is any number (including 0), but to be wiped if the user clears the textbox. However, at the moment it is treating a blank textbox and a textbox with 0 in it the same.

How can I differentiate between the two?

Comment: I don't believe that the code you posted could possibly be responsible for what you perceive to be going wrong. The comparison you've got, `NewCount != ""`, will be `true` when the value of the input box is any non-empty string, including the string "0".

Comment: Are you wanting to treat white space the same as "" ?

Comment: @Pointy - That's not how `!=` works. You need `!==`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!==` in your `if` statement.

Comment: But `"0" != ""` evaluates (as one would expect) to `true`.

Comment: why? can you provide a link or an explanation?

Comment: @Shawn - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing. In my tests a textbox with "0" in it will be considered *not* blank by Javascript using your comparison logic (!= "").

Here is my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/5404/

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( NewCount.length == 0 ) {
    // text-box is empty
} else if ( !isNaN(NewCount) ) {
    // the value is a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of the following could work

```
NewCount.length > 0
NewCount !== ''
```