# Complete Novice Programmer: Novice Guide to Java Programming

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is my situation:

I have some basic programming skills.  I have basic knowledge of networking.

I would like to start out programming Java in the Eclipse Environment.  I need some help downloading IDE though.

I have found several tutorials but would like someone on *here with android/java dev experience* to suggest a book or tutorial as i dont want to start out with one that is dated.

Question: What do i want to do with java? 
Answer: Build Websites, Android Apps, Desktop Apps

The tutorials I can find, but getting started is proving to be difficult.  If you could suggest a good way to Download the Eclipse IDE so I could get started that would be great at least. Thanks

Comment: "I need some help downloading IDE"... really ?

Comment: @David I guess i meant the right version and extionsion for android, thanks tho

Comment: first of all I wound read through this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend two books which I read and learned from:

- [Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004651) - Funny, a pleasure to read and learn from.
- [Hello, Android](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband/hello-android) - Also teaches through an example application.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Downloading the IDE is as simple as www.eclipse.org/downloads and selecting the first download available on that screen

As far as tutorials go, sun (oracle) has good tutorials on their site for java (pretty sure to not be out of date) and the exercises on android.google.com are very good also.

Just be sure to walk before your run (stay away from the platform specific stuff until you understand at least the basics of the language)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to start on the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) site and follow the setup instructions there.  In the **Preparing Your Development Computer** section they give you a link to the [Eclipse downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) page and also recommend the **Eclipse Classic** version.  This is the version that I use, and the Android SDK is fairly easy to set up and use.

I can also recommend the book [Hello, Android](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband3/hello-android).  The first section of the book takes you through the set up steps you need to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever do object oriented programming? If not, you really should by a "Learning Java" book and take some time for the basics. You will run in many problems later if you try to jump from php/perl/c to Java without deep understanding of OO. 
Probably you should start with something simpler than Networking, Swing/SWT and Android.

Answer (score 0):

The free portion of this [video course](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920004240) covers setting up Eclipse & the Android SDK. That said, I agree with other posters that you should have a decent understanding of Object Oriented programming principle (e.g. [Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004651)) before you dive into Android.

Answer (score 0):

Head first Java, http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Main_Page, The New boston. If you want FREE books, feel free to message me directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Head First Java book is great, but light switches didn't start going off until I really began to understand data structures.

I highly recommend [Data Structures Demystified](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072253592) if you want to understand what is going on under the hood.