# String as an array index

Tags: c, arrays

In `3["XoePhoenix"]`, array index is of type array of characters. Can we do this in C? Isn't it true that an array index must be an integer?

What does `3["XeoPhoenix"]` mean?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`3["XoePhoenix"]` is the same as `"XoePhoenix"[3]`, so it will evaluate to the char `'P'`.

The array syntax in C is not more than a different way of writing `*( x + y )`, where `x` and `y` are the sub expressions before and inside the brackets. Due to the commutativity of the addition these sub expressions can be exchanged without changing the meaning of the expression.

So `3["XeoPhoenix"]` is compiled as `*( 3 + "XeoPhoenix" )` where the string decays to a pointer and `3` is added to this pointer which in turn results in a pointer to the 4th char in the string. The `*` dereferences this pointer and so this expression evaluates to `'P'`.

`"XeoPhoenix"[ 3 ]` would be compiled as `*( "XeoPhoenix" + 3 )` and you can see that would lead to the same result.

Answer (score 5):

`3["XeoPhoenix"]` is equivalent to `"XeoPhoenix"[3]` and would evaluate to the 4th character i.e `'P'`.

In general `a[i]` and `i[a]` are equivalent.

```
a[i] = *(a + i) = *(i + a) = i[a]
```

Comment: Strange feature and it made it to the top of the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1995156#1995156

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays are very simple data structures with consecutive blocks of memory. They therefore need to be integers as these indices are nothing more than offsets to addresses in memory.