# Python intern for non-strings

Tags: python, language-features

Why is Python's `intern` built-in only for strings?  It should be possible to extend `intern` to classes that are hashable and comparable, right?

Comment: You could create an object cache like `intern` for immutable objects.

Comment: @Peter: you're right.  The advantage of `intern` is that all of the code for that is automatically generated, and as a bonus, it's in fast C++.

Comment: @NeilG I don't think so. AFAIK CPython is completly written in C, not C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The purpose of interning things is to be able to compare them by comparing their memory address; you ensure that you never create two objects with the same value (when the program requests the creation of a second object with the same value as an existing object, it instead receives a reference to the pre-existing object). This requires that the things you're interning be *immutable*; if the value of an interned object could change, comparing them by address isn't going to work.

In Python, it's not possible to enforce the immutability of user-defined class instances, so it wouldn't be safe to intern them. I suspect that's the main theoretical reason intern doesn't cover class instances.

Other built in immutable types are either comparable in a single machine-level operation already (int, float, etc), or immutable containers that *can contain mutable values* (tuple, frozenset). There's no need to intern the former, and the latter can't be safely interned either.

Comment: +1. "In Python, it's not possible to enforce the immutability of user-defined class instances" -- how unfortunate.

Comment: But why wouldn't something like an _empty_ `frozenset` be interned?

Comment: @MEE I see no reason why interning empty frozensets couldn't be made to work. But let me flip that around; why *would* somebody write the extra code to make sure empty frozensets are interned? Empty containers don't occupy tons of memory, and comparing them is pretty cheap. And frozensets are not the "easy default" container (like lists), so it's not very likely that people are making huge numbers of them accidentally. It's also easy to share memory yourself by just having a global `empty = frozenset()`. It doesn't seem very compelling idea when there are better things to put engineering into.

Comment: Thanks for even bothering to respond @Ben. Appreciate your response. An empty `frozenset` is 216 bytes, which is a lot of memory for an immutable empty object. Indeed one can easily use a global empty set, the same way one can use a global frozen dataclass, but it'd also be less boilerplate and cleaner if the runtime just figures out these little nuisances for us.

Comment: @MEE Interning strings is an obvious huge win for Python because objects are basically string-keyed dictionaries, so there are a lot of strings that occur a lot in every single program due to that (on *top* of the fact that strings themselves are a very common type and often repeat a lot). Interning only empty frozensets just seems like a really marginal optimisation. But if you disagree, better file a PEP rather than try to convince the audience of a 10 year old post. Either way it's a minor detail that isn't really relevant to the topic of this question & answer, which is general interning.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason that, say, a tuple could not be interned, though I would imagine that in the real world this is of little value compared to string literals, and it would be of even less real-world value with user-defined types. Making it work is probably not considered worth the effort.

Comment: The contents of a tuple can be mutable.  Interning tuples could cause weird behaviour.  E.g. `a, b = ([]), ([]); a[0].append('foo')` would have different results depending on whether `a` and `b` were different tuples which depends on the tuple interning implementation.  Apparently some implementations of Fortran [did something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1995476#1995476).

Comment: @Peter: The whole idea of interning is that you can do it only when there are no side effects like the one you describe. Interning a tuple would obviously have to check to make sure all elements are the same objects as a tuple already interned, not merely equal. It could in fact try to intern the elements first (this would be more useful if numeric types were also made internable). In your example, the tuples simply would not be able to share a reference if they didn't contain the same list. There is no technical reason why Python could not be amended to do all this.

Answer (score 0):

Only strings are supported because interning relies on a pointer-based [object identity test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Hashes of other types of classes could be compared, but the objects themselves will never match an identity test. This is true because even though they may be identical, they are not the same objects.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)

Comment: As I understand it, the pointer-based object identity test is the *benefit* you gain by interning, not what is required to intern things. If you're asking to intern objects, you're inherently considering any two of them with the same value to have the same identity (which I believe is what Neil G is getting at when he says "hashable and comparable"). That in turn requires that they are immutable, which is not an enforceable property of class instances in Python. I would guess that's the main theoretical reason it's not supported.

Comment: @Ben: That's a good interpretation of my question.  Also, your last point is probably the answer to this question.  Feel free to add an answer.