# Confused about Python’s id()

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, identity

I can understand the following definition:

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value. An object's identity
>   never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the
>   object’s address in memory. The `is` operator compares the identity of
>   two objects; the `id()` function returns an integer representing its
>   identity.

I would assume the above definition works when “something” is created, such as:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> id(a)
1720438480
```

But I do not understand:

```
>>> id(1)
1720438512
>>> b = 1
>>> id(b)
1720438512
```

I did not create anything yet; so how can the integer “1” have an ID? Does it mean that as soon as I “mention” 1 in the Python Shell, it is assigned to a memory address? Also, does it mean that because the ID never changes during its lifetime, and because my computer has a limited memory, if I repeatedly ask for the id() of unique things, I will eventually get something like “out of memory” message? (It cannot reallocate memory, because the lifetime of others have not ended yet.)

Or, showing my ear from the other way round:

```
>>> id(something_1)
some unique memory address
>>> id(something_2)
some unique memory address
>>> ...
```

At which point is the memory reallocated? That is, at which point,

```
>>> my_variable = something_1
>>> id(my_variable)
```

will give an ID that is different from `id(something_1)`?

Comment: Note that specifically for small integers, `id`s are reused as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934202/python-intern-for-non-strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, as soon as you use an integer or a string or any other literal, Python creates a new object in memory for you. It is guaranteed to have the same `id` for the lifetime of the object, that is, while its reference count is not zero.

When you write something like:

```
>>> id(1000)
140497411829680
```

Python creates the integer 1000 and returns its `id` (the memory address of the object in CPython). After this is done, the reference count of the integer object 1000 is zero and it is deleted. This ensures that you cannot keep filling memory just by writing `id(something)` (and not binding any variable name to the object).

Typically, you cannot predict when reuse will happen, but in my Python shell it happens quite consistently:

```
>>> id(1000)
140697307078576
>>> id(1001)
140697307078576
>>> id(1002)
140697307078576
>>> id(1003)
140697307078576
```

You can see that the same memory address get used again and again when each new integer is created. However, if you prevent the reference count from dropping to zero, you can see that new memory is used instead:

```
>>> a = 1000
>>> id(a)
140697307078576
>>> b = 1001
>>> id(b)
140697306008368
```

In CPython, the integers -5 through to 255 are special cases in that they *always* exist (and so always have the same `id` during a Python runtime). This is an optimisation to avoid repeated creation and destruction of commonly-used integers.

Comment: Hi Alex. What if there's a virtual memory and the program is swapped in/out many times? Wouldn't it change the physical memory address of the same variable?

Comment: CPython doesn't use garbage collection to clean out unreferenced objects. **The moment the reference count drops to 0** the object is deleted.  So yes, `id(1000)` will create an `int` object with value 1000, the only reference is the stack, `id()` produces a value for that object, the object is cleared from the stack and is deleted immediately because the reference count is now 0. Python does have a garbage collector, but all it is responsible for is to break cyclic references.

Comment: As for small numbers, the range is [from -5 through to 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).