# Python - id of pointer and object

Tags: python, object, pointers

We say that in Python, every object that is created is given a number that uniquely identifies it.

When we let a point to 500 and obtain the id of both a and 500:

```
a=500
id(a), id(500)
(140733559789896, 140733559789992)
```

does this mean that the ID of the reference a (140733559789896) "points" to object 500 like a points to 500?

And why is 140733559789992 not the id of the object 500?

Comment: Somewhat, it means that 500 is not interned (or whatever it called in Python) and as result 500 stored in `a` is different from any other 500... Try the same with `5`. (Should be duplicate... someone will find it shortly)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about Python’s id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801444/confused-about-python-s-id)

Comment: **python doesn't have pointers**. In any case, why is this surprising to you? You've merely created two different objects

Answer (score 0):

`id(500)` creates a new object in memory and assigns an id to it. This is not the same object as `a`, even if they share the same value.

Imagine we have this piece of code:

```
a = 500
b = 500
```

Do we expect `id(a) == id(b)`? Of course not – they're different objects.

Comment: not always true, try a=10, b=10, id(a)==id(b) ..  https://www.journaldev.com/22925/python-id - short but interesting

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean that the ID of the reference a (140733559789896) "points" to object 500 like a points to 500?

According to the docs for [id](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id), it's the address of the object `500` in memory.

> And why is 140733559789992 not the id of the object 500?

It is.
The `500` in the line `a = 500` and the `500` you pass to `id(500)` in line 2 are different objects, hence the different identities.