# Swapping variables and list elements in Python works unexpectedly

Tags: python, variables, swap

I have just came up with an example of code:

```
ls = [2222, 1111]

a = ls[0]
print(a is ls[0])

a, ls[1] = ls[1], a
print(ls)
```

which prints:

```
True
[2222, 2222]
```

My question is, why isn't `a` the same object as `ls[0]` in the above case? The `a is ls[0]` check is `True`, therefore it must be the same as:

```
ls[0], ls[1] = ls[1], ls[0]
```

but it isn't. The latter one produces `[1111, 2222]`. What is this mYsTeRy?

Comment: Neither ``a`` nor ``ls[1]`` are objects themselves. They *evaluate to* objects, which happen to be identical during the first ``print``.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Comment: @RandomDavis no, it doesn't. I picked values over 256 to make sure it doesn't cause any trouble.

Comment: Okay then how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33801660/6273251)?

Comment: @RandomDavis I don't think either of these are helpful. The "issue" would be the same with mutable objects as well.

Comment: @RandomDavis nope. It has next to zero relation to my question.

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple assignments have no affect on the *previous* value of the target.

After

```
ls = [2222, 1111]

a = ls[0]
```

both `a` and the first element of `ls` are references to the integer `2222`.

The assignment

```
a, ls[1] = ls[1], a
```

is effectively the same as

```
t = ls[1], a  # The tuple (1111, 2222)
a = t[0]  # Set a to t[0] == 1111
ls[1] = t[1]  # Set ls[1] to t[1] == 2222
```

At no point have you modified the first element of `ls`; you've only changed what `a` refers to and what the second element of `ls` refers to. You can see that `a` is now refers to `1111`, since that's what the value of `ls[1]` was *before* `ls[1]` was modified.

```
>>> print(a)
1111
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting ls[0]!

Fixing it:

```py
ls = [2222, 1111]

# Assigns ls[0] to a, but not changes ls[0]!
a = ls[0]
print(a is ls[0])

# Assigns ls[1] to a and a to ls[1]. At this point ls[1] is a!
a, ls[1] = ls[1], a
print(ls)

# Now ls[0] is assigned!
ls[0] = a
print(ls)
```

Outputs:

```
True
[2222, 2222]
[1111, 2222]
```

BTW: You can do the reverse listing with:

```py
ls = [2222, 1111]
print(ls[::-1])
```

Outputs:

```
[1111, 2222]
```

Comment: I still don't understand why it doesn't set `l[0]`. My `a is ls[0]` proved that they are the same object.

Comment: @AleksandrNovik `a` is just a name. Not an object. The fact that both the name `a`  and `l[0]` refer to the same object doesn't mean that changing which object one name points to effects the other.

Comment: They are two *references* to the same object. Subsequent assignments to the name `a` have nothing to do with any other references to `a`'s old value.

Comment: @chepner is right.

Answer (score 0):

Taken literally, neither `a` nor `ls[1]` are objects: They are an [identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-identifier) and [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions), respectively. While they *evaluate to* objects when used in an expression, that does not make them identical to these objects – and the identity of "their" objects does not extend to them, either.

- The expression `a is ls[0]` means "evaluate `a` and `ls[0]` and compare *the result* for identity". It does not check whether the identifier `a` is identical to the subscription `ls[0]`.

Notably, when used in an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), both `a` and `ls[1]` do not represent "an expression to look up an object" but rather "a target to assign an object to". The features of the former do not impact the latter.

---

The statement `a, ls[1] = ls[1], a` uses both `a` and `ls[1]` as both expressions and targets:

- The right hand side is an expression. It represents "a tuple of the results of evaluating `ls[1]` and `a`".
- The left hand side is an assignment. It represents "assign to the identifier `a` and the subscription `ls[1]`".

Assignment to an identifier always is immediate: it does not matter what value the identifier previously referred to. Specifically, it does not matter that `a` previously referred to an object that was also referred to by `ls[0]`, and it will not matter that its new referent was also referred to by `ls[1]`.

---

To understand why this distinction is important, consider the case that an identifier "is identical to" a literal:

```py
>>> # integers < 256 are interned
>>> a = 12
>>> # identifier "is identical to" literal
>>> a is 12
True
```

If identity in expressions would equate to identity in assignments, then setting `a = 13` would now reassign both `a` *and `12`* to have the value `13`.

Answer (score -2):

This code would not work as in this case you have a reference to the object at `ls[0]` and not a reference to the memory position of `ls[0]`.

Comment: `a` is not a copy. `a` is a reference to the integer 2222, just as `ls[0]` is a reference to the same integer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... I will leave only the reason why the question is wrong to avoid mistakes