# How does interning work with immutable objects?

Tags: python, tuples, immutability, python-3.5

If I am not mistaken `a is b` should return `True` if `a` and `b` point to the same object. With two equal lists it returns `False` because the lists are two different lists. I thought that immutable objects didn't have this problem but when I put in:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (1, 2, 3)
a is b #returns false
```

I thought that this should return `True` since `a` and `b` point to an immutable object that has the same value. Why isn't `a` pointing to the same object as `b` when I use tuples?

Comment: Not all immutable objects are interned.

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20(1,%202,%203%29%0Ab%20%3D%20(1,%202,%203%29%0Aa%20is%20b%20%23returns%20false&cumulative=true&curInstr=3&heapPrimitives=true&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6934202/4996248

Answer (score 5):

Your a and b do *not* point to the same object (you create two individual tuples); you can inspect that with `id(a)` or -- as you did -- with `a is b`.

```
a == b
```

on the other hand will be `True`.

If you want them to point to the same object you could do

```
a = b = (1, 2, 3)
```

Now `a is b` is `True`.

None of this has to do with mutability or immutability; it would work the same if you took `list`s instead of `tuple`s.

You can visualize your code [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to see what is happening.

Python does intern some strings and some small integers (e.g. `a=0; b=0; a is b` yields `True`) but not all immutables are interned. Furthermore you should not rely on that, rather consider it an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should never rely on the details on what gets does and doesn't get interned. It is completely implementation dependent, and could change from point release to point release.

Interning is designed solely to be an optimization to reduce memory usage, and you are correct that in principle any literal of an immutable value could be interned, but that's only actually done in the most trivial of cases.

One likely reason that tuples aren't interned is that they're not deeply immutable. If you put something mutable inside them (such as `({}, [])`), interning them could lead to incorrect behavior, as modifying one could modify the other.

You could of course check whether a tuple contains only immutable objects, but tuples can be nested arbitrarily deeply, so you'd have to do work to verify that a tuple only (transitively) contains immutable objects, and that's really not worth it, because you can always "manually intern" them if you want.

```
a = 1, 2, 3
b = a
```