# Why parenthesis don't change the operator priority for == and === in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of confused! Why paranthesis don't affect the priority in these statements?

```
true === '0' == 0 // returns true
(true === '0') == 0 // returns true again!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that the priority is different, it's that both groupings evaluate to true:

`true === '0'` is `false`
`false == 0` is `true`

`'0' == 0` is `true`
`true === true` is `true`

You might want to review the [JS truth table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224)

Comment: But it *is* that the expressions *are the same* -- and to blow this off is a big oversight. Consider adding the case `true === ('0' == 0)` to show the parenthesis actually doing something (which would generate the second case). Good answer otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

because `true === '0'` evaluates to `false`, and `false == 0` is true. (because `false` and 0 are both "non-truthy")

Remember that `===` compares strict equality and `==` tests for equality with conversion.

Answer (score 6):

Because `(true === '0')` is false and `false == 0` is true in both cases.

In other words:

`(true === '0') == 0`

resolves to

`false == 0`

Which is true.

Answer (score 4):

Because the operators `===` and `==` have the [*same precedence*](http://www.tipsntracks.com/345/learning-javascript-tutorial-javascript-operator-precedence-and-associativity.html) are are left-to-right associative. Both the expressions result in the *same* interpretation. Consider the following expressions as for why the result is what it is:

```
true === '0' // false
// so: true === '0' == 0    is  false == 0    and;
//     (true === '0') == 0  is  (false) == 0  is  false == 0  and;
false == 0   // true
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
> true === '0'
  false
> false == 0
  true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(true === '0') == 0
```

This one evaluates to:

```
false == 0 // which is true
```

Answer (score 1):

Because (true === '0') is false and false == 0 is true and in this case JavaScript is nt doing a strict type comparison if you want it to return false change second part to ===

Answer (score 1):

because true === '0' return false and false == 0 return true

Even with the paranthesis, your first check will always return false and

```
false == 0 will always return true
```

The === will check if the value is exactly the same (type inculded).  So since you compare a char with a boolean, the result will alway be false.

Answer (score 0):

By using parenthesis, you have not changed the order of execution. It was left to right even without parenthesis. The left part true=='0' returns 0.

0 == 0 returns true, so final answer is true both the times.