# Javascript 0 Vs Blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a variable x = ""

And I check for the following condition
if x != 0

Is it evaluated as false across all the browsers ?

Why is 0 treated the same as "" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close as duplicate; even if the relevant answer is there, the question is not remotely the same.

Comment: Jeremy : Strongly agree with you...It is NOT AT ALL a duplicate..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `==` operator JavaScript attempts to convert both operands to the same type for comparison. When you have a string and a number it attempts to convert the string to a number. `""` converts to `0`, giving you this result.

Because of this behaviour many people chose to use the `===` and `!==` operators instead. Their operands must be the same type to be considered equal.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that in the case of one string and one number across `=`, JavaScript will convert the string to a number first.  However "finding no value" is not the real reason that the empty string is converted to zero.  The string `"dog"` is converted to `NaN`, even though you could argue it couldn't "find a value" :-)

Comment: @Ray, agree, another example, a string consisting only on white-space characters, e.g. `" \t\n\r"` is also converted to `0`, just like the empty string...

Answer (score 1):

Because both `0` and `''` are evaluated like this:

```
0 == false  //true
'' == false //true
```

Use `===` to check properly

Comment: Actually that is not true.  `0` does not "evaluate to" false, nor does the empty string "evaluate to" false.  What happens when a string and a number are compared with `==`, JavaScript attempts to convert the string to a number and then do a numeric equality comparison.  It has nothing at all to do with falsiness in this case.  That's probably why `==` gets such a bad rap.  No one really understands it.  Try `null == 0` for example.  They are both falsy, but they are not `==` to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Is `""` that when casted is egual to `0`:

`"" != 0` -> `string != int` -> `(int)string != int` -> `int != int`