# How does JavaScript convert types when comparing with == ?

Tags: javascript

```
alert (0 == ''); // true
alert (0 == '0'); // true
```

[JSFiddle Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/FuQe5/)

I understand that == in javascript performs a conversion and then checks for equality, but how does it perform the conversion in the statements above? Does it convert 0 to '' or '' to 0? Or something else perhaps? Is there a spec somewhere that explains the implementation?

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/1998224#1998224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3).

Specifically for your example

> If `Type(x)` is `Number` and `Type(y)` is `String`,
>   return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

So then you'll end up with:

```
0 == 0
```

...in both cases because an empty string converts to the number `0`, and a numeric string converts to the number given.

From [9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1):

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to `+0`

Since we're now doing a comparison of the same Type on the second pass, it will do the following:

> If `Type(x)` is the same as `Type(y)`, then
>
> ...
>   If `Type(x)` is `Number`, then
>
> ...
>   If `x` is the same `Number` value as `y`, return `true`.

---

To test a `toNumber` conversion, you can use the unary `+` operator.

```
console.log( +'' );   // 0
console.log( +'0' );  // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The specification is [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

The algorithm is given in 11.9.3, The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm.

For both, "Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, [] return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y)"

ToNumber is in 9.3.  MV stands for "mathematical value."  I think the rules that apply are:

- "The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0."
- "The MV of StrNumericLiteral ::: StrDecimalLiteral is the MV of StrDecimalLiteral"

In other words, an empty string converts to 0, and '0' is just a regular decimal in string form.

Comment: You've specified the section, so it isn't as big a deal, but there is also an [Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5), so it's a good idea to include *Equality* in the title.

Comment: @patrick, thanks.  That's what I get for not copy and pasting.

Comment: Even though the down-vote came when the answer only consisted of the first sentence, in fairness, even then it did answer the final question that OP was asking *"Is there a spec somewhere that explains the implementation?"*. +1 to offset and for the update.

Answer (score 1):

How this is converted is covered in section 11.9.3 in the EMCA 262 spec.  The following rule is applicable to this scenario (where `x == y`)

> if Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String then convert y to a number and compare

In both examples here JavaScript will convert `y` to a number and both will result in `0` so the comparison is `true`