# TSQL LEN function returns a 1 when evaluating a zero-length integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have found the LEN function does not return a zero when it evaluates an integer when the integer has no value - it returns a 1.

For example:

```
declare @int1 int
set @int1 = ''
select LEN(@int1)
```

A 1 is returned instead of a zero! But the integer is zero-length!

Why is this? Is it a bug?

Comment: FYI, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2008906#2008906

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An INT doesn't have a length.  This is what you are actually doing...

- Create an INT variable
- Create a zero length string `''`
- CAST that string to an INT `0`
- Assign the result to the variable
- CAST the variable's value to a STRING `'0'`
- Caclulate the length of that string

The result of which is that your LEN function is not being called on '', but is infact being called on '0', which has a length of 1.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known that.

Answer (score 2):

you should assign NULL to integers for them to mean "i have no value"

something like this:

```
declare @int1 int 
set @int1 = null
select @int1 
union
select LEN(isnull(cast(@int1 as varchar),''))
```

returns

```
NULL
0
```

Answer (score 1):

int1 will be initialised as '0' so  it is returning the correct result:

```
declare @int1 int set @int1 = '' 
select @int1
select LEN(@int1)
```

Returns:

0

1