# Undesirable behavior of javascript operator

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why this is happening,

```
console.info("") //(an empty string)

console.info(0)  //0

console.info(typeof "") //string

console.info(typeof 0) //number

console.info(""==0) //true

console.info(0=="") //true

console.info (0>="") //true

console.info ("">=0) //true
```

Shouldn't it return false for last four statements.

I did all these in FireBug, a firefox addons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1998224/576139

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECMAScript Equals Operator (==) uses the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm, see [ECMA-262 §11.9.3](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3).

Comment: If anyone wants to know how all possible comparisons work, you have to go read this spec.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference link.

Answer (score 2):

The last 4 statements involve **implicit type casting** via the logical comparison operators. Because a `String` and `Number` are being compared, the `String` is converted to a `Number`. `""` turns into `0` which is equal to `0`.

[You can find it in the specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3) <sub>which is not an easy read IMO</sub>:

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), go to step 14.
> 2. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is not Number, go to step 11.
> 5. If x is NaN, return false.
> 6. If y is NaN, return false.
> 7. If x is the same number value as y, return true.
> 8. If x is +0 and y is -0, return true.
> 9. If x is -0 and y is +0, return true.
> 10. Return false.
> 11. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions). Otherwise, return false.
> 12. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false. Otherwise, return false.
> 13. Return true if x and y refer to the same object or if they refer to objects joined to each other (see 13.1.2). Otherwise, return false.
> 14. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 15. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 16. **If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == [ToNumber](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3)(y).**
> 17. **If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3)(x)== y.**
> 18. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3)(x)== y.
> 19. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == [ToNumber](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3)(y).
> 20. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 21. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x)== y.
> 22. Return false.

Comment: @Hoque - yes, the values are different types, but as zzzzBov said, the `==` operators attempts to convert them to the same type - if it can do so and after conversion they are equal it returns true. An empty string can be converted to 0, so...

Comment: Type casting does not explain all of it, e.g. `2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true`—no type casting there, just a straight rule for the result of a particular comparison. Nor does it explain how the types are cast, e.g. if x is Boolean and y is String, both are converted to Number before comparison.

Comment: @nnnnnn, does javascript changes the comparer type to number when comparing with any number like 0 (here)?

Comment: For example ""==0, according to the steps above I should go 1-->then 14 and then no decision...

Comment: No, it goes to 14 which doesn't apply, then 15 which doesn't apply, then 16 which doesn't apply, then 17 which _does_ apply. An empty string is still a string.

Answer (score 1):

well you have run into javascripts falsey and truthy value concept. In javascript

```
Truthy: Something which evaluates to TRUE.
Falsey: Something which evaluates to FALSE.
```

It’s mostly logical. One (1) is truthy, Zero (0) is falsey. An object of any kind (including functions, arrays, RegExp objects, etc.) is always truthy. The easiest way to determine if something is truthy is to determine that it’s not falsey. There are only five falsey values in JavaScript:

```
undefined, null, NaN, 0, "" (empty string), and false.
```

Thus when you end up comparing two falsey values using the Abstract Equality Comparer it returns true.

To get around the problem use the typesafe comparison by using the `===` operator

Comment: If one operand is a string and the other is a number, `==` will convert the string to a number and then do a number comparison. Falsey and truthy don't come into it.

Comment: I have tested for console.info("Apple"==4) //returns false.

Comment: well you are correct in saying that there is a conversion I am just saying after the conversion what is the comparison like.. I think the conversion part is discussed already