# Is true == 1 and false == 0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I was reading a good book on JavaScript.

It started with:

> Boolean type take only two literal values: true and false. These are distinct from numeric values, so true is not equal to 1, and false is not equal to 0.

However, I observed following:

```
if(1==true)
  document.write("oh!!! that's true");  //**this is displayed**
```

I know, that every type in JavaScript has a Boolean equivalent.

But then, what's the truth?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: Another very close question (although the one from @Jeroen has a  better answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265401/undesirable-behavior-of-javascript-operator

Comment: Which "good book" are we talking about here?

Comment: @Pointy Its Wrox Professional JavaScript

Comment: @Mahesha999 ok, that is a good book :)  I asked because there are, sadly, quite a few not-so-good JavaScript books out there.

Comment: can you name the book please?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's true that `true` and `false` don't represent any numerical values in Javascript.

In some languages (e.g. C, VB), the boolean values are defined as actual numerical values, so they are just different names for 1 and 0 (or -1 and 0).

In some other languages (e.g. Pascal, C#), there is a distinct boolean type that is not numerical. It's possible to convert between boolean values and numerical values, but it doesn't happen automatically.

Javascript falls in the category that has a distinct boolean type, but on the other hand Javascript is quite keen to convert values between different data types.

For example, eventhough a number is not a boolean, you can use a numeric value where a boolean value is expected. Using `if (1) {...}` works just as well as `if (true) {...}`.

When comparing values, like in your example, there is a difference between the `==` operator and the `===` operator. The `==` equality operator happily converts between types to find a match, so `1 == true` evaluates to true because `true` is converted to `1`. The  `===` type equality operator doesn't do type conversions, so `1 === true` evaluates to false because the values are of different types.

Comment: If numbers such as `1` is indeed converted to `true` for the comparison, then why doesn't `2 == true` also evaluate to true? To prove that `2` is also considered `true` when converted to a Boolean, `!!2 == true` evaluates to true.

Comment: @user193130: Sorry, that was a mistake in the answer, when you compare them, the conversion is from boolean to number. The `true` is converted to `1`, so `1 == true` evaluates to true, while `2 == true` evaluates to false. When you use a value as a condition, the conversion has to be to boolean, because that is the only type that a condition can be.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Just tested `+true === 1` and it evaluates true.

Comment: And I think it is pretty confusing, that -1 equals true in JavaScript! For example if you do
if(str.indexOf("something")){ dosomething(); }
It does even when "something" is not found in str variable.

Comment: @McVitas: The `indexOf` method isn't meant to be used that way. Even if `-1` was interpreted as `false`, it would not work if the string is found at the first position. As `indexOf` returns `0` if the string is found at the first position, that would also be interpreted as `false`. You could use `if(str.indexOf("something") + 1)`, but that's pretty obscure, it's better to just look for the special value `-1` using `if(str.indexOf("something") != -1)`.

Comment: if you don't use things like `if (array.length)` instead of `if (array.length > 0)` you are a bad programmer.

Answer (score 44):

> In JavaScript, == is pronounced "Probably Equals".

What I mean by that is that JavaScript will automatically convert the Boolean into an integer and then attempt to compare the two sides.

For real equality, use the === operator.

Comment: Actually, it converts the Integer into a Boolean, and then compares, but right idea.

Comment: @nonrectangular Just confirmed that it actually converts from a Boolean to an Integer; see comments in the answer above and also [João Silva's explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236648/2891365) below.

Comment: Actually, what the `==` chekcs is called "IsLooselyEqual"

Answer (score 15):

Try the strict equality comparison:

```
if(1 === true)
    document.write("oh!!! that's true");  //**this is not displayed**
```

The `==` operator does conversion from one type to another, the `===` operator doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

From the ECMAScript specification, Section **[11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)**:

> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> - If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison **x == ToNumber(y)**.

Thus, in, `if (1 == true)`, `true` gets coerced to a `Number`, i.e. `Number(true)`, which results in the value of `1`, yielding the final `if (1 == 1)` which is `true`.

`if (0 == false)` is the exact same logic, since `Number(false) == 0`.

This doesn't happen when you use the strict equals operator `===` instead:

> [**11.9.6 The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm**](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)
>
> The comparison x === y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> - If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return **false**.

Comment: This answers my question - Will the Boolean gets converted to Number / Number gets converted to Boolean ? 
The answer is - *Boolean gets converted to Number*

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the dreaded loose comparison operator strikes again. Never use it. Always use strict comparison, === or !== instead.

Bonus fact: `0 == ''`

Comment: why 0==' ' is true? while " "=="0" is false?

Comment: @Ankita, both are same type here " " == "0"

Answer (score 3):

When compare something with Boolean it works like following

Step 1: Convert `boolean` to `Number`   `Number(true) // 1` and `Number(false) // 0`

Step 2: Compare both sides

```
boolean == someting 
-> Number(boolean) === someting
```

If compare `1` and `2` with `true` you will get the following results

```
true == 1
-> Number(true) === 1
-> 1 === 1
-> true
```

And

```
true == 2
-> Number(true) === 1
-> 1 === 2
-> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually every object in javascript resolves to true if it has "a real value" as W3Cschools puts it. That means everything except `""`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null` or `0`.

Testing a number against a boolean with the `==` operator indeed is a tad weird, since the boolean gets converted into numerical 1 before comparing, which defies a little bit the logic behind the definition.
This gets even more confusing when you do something like this:

```js
    var fred = !!3; // will set fred to true 
    var joe = !!0; // will set joe to false
    alert("fred = "+ fred + ", joe = "+ joe);
```

not everything in javascript makes a lot of sense ;)

Comment: "not everything in javascript makes a lot of sense" - this example makes perfect sense if you understand type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` to equate the variables instead of `==`.

`==` checks if the value of the variables is similar

`===` checks if the value of the variables and the type of the variables are similar

Notice how

```
if(0===false) {
    document.write("oh!!! that's true");
}​
```

and

```
if(0==false) {
    document.write("oh!!! that's true");
}​
```

give different results

Answer (score 0):

### In a way, yes it is 1.

Try these examples in Chrome console:

```js
> 2==true
false

> 1==true
true

> true + 1
2

> true + 2
3

> true + true
2
```

So, the answer is:

- **yes**, as soon as you use `true` in any arithmetical context, it's treated as numeric 1, or as Bruce Lee would say, it *becomes* one. The same way, false is practically zero. But also,
- **no**, if you ask Javascript what it thinks of `true`, it will say it's a boolean:

```js
> typeof true
'boolean'
```

It's no surprise in a loosely typed language that sometimes things are not what they are but how you look at them. And if you add `true` to a string, it will not add `1` but `"true"` as a string, so at the end of the day, it's by no means equivalent to one. Let me end this with a horrible pun:

> true is not a number - but it looks like one

Answer (score -1):

with == you are essentially comparing whether a variable is falsey when comparing to false or truthey when comparing to true.  If you use ===, it will compare the exact value of the variables so true will not === 1