# Why does my loop stop when the number is 0?

Tags: javascript

```js
function enigma(inputValue) {
  var i = 0;
  while (inputValue) {
    if (++i == 5) inputValue = 0;
  }
  return i;
}
var whatAmI = enigma(5);
console.log(whatAmI);
```

```html
<div>Hit F12 and go to the console to view output.</div>
```

The output I get is 5.

Why does JavaScript stop the loop if `inputValue` equals 0? Is this because I did not specify that as the condition in the while loop?

Comment: What did you specify as the condition?

Comment: inputvalue is my condition in the while loop.

Comment: When does `inputValue` become false?

Comment: while needs a value which is true, 0 is false, while 1 is an infinite loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is true == 1 and false == 0 in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236271/is-true-1-and-false-0-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This explains the basics of a while loop. The condition within the while loop checks if it is truthy/falsy. When i is equal to 5, the input is 0, which causes the condition to be false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

If you want to see some other crazy Javascript, check out these truthy/falsy examples.

http://blog.falafel.com/the-truth-about-false-in-javascript/

Answer (score -1):

0 is false. You can [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_boolean_zero)

Comment: Thank man, I never knew the value 0 is seen as a false in javascript.

Comment: logically 0 is always false and 1 is true

Comment: @Mocrosoft you can read more about JavaScript booleans here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp

Comment: @DanielRuf Except in bash/when dealing with program exit codes.

Comment: Right, but this does not use boolean values but integer or strings.