# get element from array which is not in first array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I have two array of objects in javascript

```
var arr1 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'}];
var arr2 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'d':'4'}];
```

I want to get the element from arr2 which is not in the arr1.
my output will be `[{'d':'4'}]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: is this work for array of objects?

Comment: None of the elements in `arr2` are in `arr1`, they are all different?

Comment: you can use loops, filter, reduce.. there are several ways, what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Comment: Define "element is in array". All the objects in your question have different references, so JS considers them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method that came my mind is using JSON.stringify:

```js
var arr1 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'}];
var arr2 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'d':'4'}];

stringArr1 = JSON.stringify(arr1);
var result = arr2.filter(
  obj => !~stringArr1.indexOf(JSON.stringify(obj))
);

console.log(result);
```

But there should be better ways.

---

The equivalent of:

```
var result = arr2.filter(
  obj => !~stringArr1.indexOf(JSON.stringify(obj))
);
```

is the common:

```
var result = arr2.filter(function (obj) {
  var stringObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
  if (stringArr1.indexOf(stringObj) != -1)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
});
```

The tricks are simple, basically you need to know 3 things:

1. All non-zero numbers are true. [SO link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236341/6188402)
2. The bitwise not (`~`) turns -1 into 0. [MDN link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)
3. Inline arrow functions (`=>`) does not need `return` keyword. [MDN link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If u dont mind can u explain `obj => !~stringArr1.indexOf(JSON.stringify(obj))` this line and tell me the use of "~".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.grep()`, `.every()`, `Object.keys()`

```js
var arr1 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'}];
var arr2 = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'d':'4'}];
var res = $.grep(arr2, function(v) {
             return arr1.every(function(_v) {
               var keys = [Object.keys(v)[0], Object.keys(_v)[0]];
               return keys[0] !== keys[1] && v[keys[0]] !== _v[keys[1]]
             })
          });
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if i use other objects ,Uncaught TypeError: arr1.every is not a function is comming

Comment: _"if i use other objects"_ What do you mean by "other objects"? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: i use other data instead of "arr1" and "arr2" data

Comment: What is "other data"? Can you fork jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1neqy2e5/ to demonstrate? Include "other data" at Question?

Comment: @GowthamV. `every` is a function of `Array.prototype`, you can't use it with _other data_.

Comment: i ll add the image in question.please find there

Comment: @GowthamV The image does not provide text of what `arr1` and `arr2` are? Can you fork jsfiddle at link to demonstrate? Also, at image `arr1` and `arr2` appear to be same array?

Comment: @GowthamV Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for each element of the arrays and use a hash table for checking

```js
var arr1 = [{ 'a': '1' }, { 'b': '2' }, { 'c': '3' }],
    arr2 = [{ 'a': '1' }, { 'b': '2' }, { 'd': '4' }],
    arr3,
    hash = Object.create(null);

arr1.forEach(function (o) {
    hash[JSON.stringify(o)] = true;
});

arr3 = arr2.filter(function (o) {
    return !hash[JSON.stringify(o)];
});

console.log(arr3);
```