# falsy expressions with double equals

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code:

```
var foo=10;
foo==true //false
```

return false? Shouldn´t be true, since any number is true?

Comment: Answered previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236341/1024832.  The gist is that `true` converts to `1`.  To coerce a number to a boolean, you can double-not it like this:  `!!foo==true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of context. If `foo` is initialized as in your code

```
var foo = 10;
```

then

```
if (foo) alert("it's true!");
```

will fire the `alert()` because in that context the `if` test is just the value of the variable, which is the "truthy" value 10.

However, the comparison `foo == true` is a different context: it's the "abstract" equality operation. There, a comparison between a number and a boolean first forces the boolean to be converted to a number. That turns `true` into 1, by definition. Then the comparison is made, and 10 is clearly not equal to 1.

There's rarely a reason to explicitly compare expression values to `true` or `false`. If you want to see if a value is "truthy" (a value you know is numeric, but you don't know the *exact* value), you can get the same result that the `if` test would get with:

```
var isTruthy = !!foo;
```

That applies the `!` boolean complement operator *twice* to the value of `foo`. The first application first converts 10 to `true` and then inverts that to `false`. The second application converts that `false` back to `true`, so the value of `isTruthy` will be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

In your comparison, `true` is turned into `1` because `foo` is a number.
Check this example snippet:

```js
var foo = 10;
console.log("foo: " + foo);
console.log(foo==true);

var foo = 1;
console.log("foo: " + foo);
console.log(foo==true);
```

You may also want to learn about strict comparison, that will prevent a comparison between a number and a boolean to return a `true` value:

```js
var foo = 1;
console.log("foo: " + foo);
console.log("Regular comparison: " + (foo==true));
console.log("Strict comparison: " + (foo===true));
```

[Link to “Comparison_Operators”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)