# Why does '1' == true return true, yet '2' == true return false in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I would like to know why '1' == true returns true but '2' == true returns false. Coming from Java background, type coercion in Javascript has been quite difficult to grasp

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236271/is-true-1-and-false-0-in-javascript

Comment: Get used to always using `===` for strict equality

Answer (score 3):

My answer is based off [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using).

In your example, operand A is a String, and operand B is boolean. So then it calls `ToNumber` on both of them and compares them for strict (`===`) equality.

`ToNumber('2') === 2`, but `ToNumber(true) === 1`, so the two are not equal.

A more in-depth explanation of the implementation is [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9).

Comment: Why, when A is a string and B is a boolean, does it decide to call 'ToNumber' to decide equality, rather than, say, 'toString'?

Comment: Because that's what they decided when they wrote the standard, that's really all there is to it. You can read the technical standard's section on [equality](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9), though it's not much more illuminating.

Comment: I get it now. thanks @CalvinGodfrey for the enlightenment

Answer (score 0):

basically it comes down to truthy and falsy values in Javascript.

since your comparison is done with == this basically means just value comparison.

among other things in Javascript, true is equal to 1 in value, just like false is equal to 0 in value. also, given the fact that u used == instead of ===, it's the same as 1 == '1' but 1 !== '1'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You couldn't have explained it more clearer