# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' (help)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def get_user_list(message, datatype):
    while True:
        str_input = input(message)
        if str_input == '':
            print('Error: Received no input.')
        for i in range(str_input - 1):
            if datatype == 'int':
                try:
                    return int(str_input)
                except ValueError: 
                    print("Error: Element '" + str_input[i] + "' is not of type " + datatype + ".")
            elif datatype == 'float':
                try:
                    return float(str_input)
                except ValueError: 
                    print("Error: Element '" + str_input[i] + "' is not of type " + datatype + ".")

            else: 
                 return str_input
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with it... somone please help... THANKS

Comment: You may have been tricked by lesser languages to think that automatic type conversion is good. Perl and Javascript, for example allows, `"5" - 1`. Python does not, because it is in fact a monumentally bad idea. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995298/126214

Comment: Also, I don't understand what the for loop is for.

Answer (score 3):

As the return value of `input()`, `str_input` is a string.  (You may already have figured this out, since you named the variable accordingly.)  In the expression `range(str_input - 1)` you try to subtract an integer from this string, which is impossible.  You also need to convert the input to an integer first, for example `range(int(str_input) - 1)`.  Note that your error checking is insufficient for this, since not every non-empty string can be converted to an integer. (Moreover, when you detect an empty string, you just print an error message and carry on, which will not work.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this code is a bit of a mess.

1. `range` only takes integers as parameters, and you are passing a string. If you are trying to loop through all characters of the string, you should pass the *length* of the string, like this:  `range(len(str_input))`. If you are trying to loop through all words in the input, you'd have to first split it into a sequence, like this: `words = str_input.split(); for i in range(len(words)):: ...`. It still wouldn't be very pythonic, but you probably don't care about that.
2. type comparison is not done comparing strings. You do it like this: `type(myvar) == int`. Note the absence of quotes around the type name.
3. `datatype` is never defined. Note that the characters or words you get from str_input would always be of type str; if you wanted other types, you'd have to explicitly convert them, and at that point type comparison would be useless (you'd already know the type, right?).
4. If you were trying to check if some string represents int or float, you'd do something like this:

   ```
   try:
       myvar = int(word)
   except ValueError:
       print('this is not an integer')
   ```
5. In your error messages you are passing only one character of the input. This is fine; however, if you are really working on single characters, it doesn't make any sense to compare types: a single character can only be either an int or a letter, it could never be a float (a float has decimals; how can you express decimals with only one character?). If you really are interested in single characters, you can just use their methods:

   ```
   >>> "a".isdigit()
   False
   >>> "1".isdigit()
   True
   ```

If this is a school exercise, you have to think better about what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code as per the above posts.

If you want to what is the type of a variable just write

```
x=10
print (x.__class__)
x = "My Name"  
type(x)
```

This would give you the types of the variable and you can easily identify what in the method is causing a problem.