# Zero should not save in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, sql-server-2000

FlexGrid

While saving the flexgrid empty cell values, it is saving as 0 in table

For Example

Flexgrid

```
ID Value1 Value2

001 1 
002 
....
```

Saving...

Query

```
With flexgrid

 insert into table1 values (NULLIF('" & .TextMatrix(i, 0) & "', '0'), NULLIF('" & .TextMatrix(i, 1) & "', '0'), NULLIF('" & .TextMatrix(i, 2) & "', '0'))

End with
```

Table1

```
ID Value1 Value2

001 1 0
002 0 0
```

It should not allow save '0' values in the table, It should save as the null column.

Expected Output

ID Value1 Value2

```
001 1 
002
```

How to solve the probelm.

Need Help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your columns are int, you are sending an empty string is [implicitly converted to zero when stored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008906/27535). So your NULLIF needs to test for empty string. The zero occurs after the NULLIF has ben processed.

Also: **Do not** concatenate strings to build SQL statement. Parametrise to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

This might be better handled on the server side e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddThing
@ID INTEGER, 
@Value1 INTEGER = NULL,
@Value2 INTEGER = NULL
AS
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (@ID, NULLIF(@Value1, 0), NULLIF(@Value2, 0));
```

Then call the proc from VB using a Command object with strongly typed Parameter objects,