# Validation on a JS function

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a list of people that are being added via a search. Everything works, but there's one case where if you don't select a person from this list, you get an ugly 400 page. Obviously it's because I'm not handling the validation there.

My "remove from list" button is done this way:

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="delTeamNominee(document.f.teamList.value)"/>
```

Here's my function:

```
function delTeamNominee(id) {
    document.dl.empId.value = id;
    document.dl.submit();        
}
```

`dl` is a hidden form that executes a Spring MVC method:

```
 <form name="dl" action="teamDeleteEmployee" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="empId">
</form>
```

Obviously I would like to do something like this:

```
function delTeamNominee(id) {
    if (id == null) {
         alert("You must select a person");
    } else {
         document.dl.empId.value = id;
         document.dl.submit();
    }
}
```

Which of course, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should also check to see if id is undefined.  Something like the following will catch both null and undefined:

if (!id) {
   ....
}

Comment: 0 is also considered to be falsey, and would evaluate as such in that if statement.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1998224/17803

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was missing.