# Weird: can not change the value of Integer in jni

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I write a jni function to set the value of two java Integer object in C, just like this:

```
jni_do_something(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject p1, jobject p2) {
    jclass c;
    jfieldID id;
    c = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
    if (c==NULL)
    {
        LOGD("FindClass failed");
        return -1;
    }

    id = env->GetFieldID(c, "value", "I");
    if (id==NULL)
    {
        LOGD("GetFiledID failed");
        return -1;
    }

    env->SetIntField(p1, id, 5);
    env->SetIntField(p2, id, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

In java, I called this function:

```
native int do_something(Integer p1, Integer p2);

Integer p1=0, p2=0;
do_something(p1, p2);
Log.d("test", "p1: "+p1);
Log.d("test", "p2: "+p2);
```

The output are both '10', why?

===============================================

I have done many tests, and got the following points. (Answer, comments are welcome)

1. I don't think this jni native is unable to alter immutable object. After all, the both objects are changed to 10 from 0.
2. There is some relation to auto-boxing (yes? I'm not sure). Maybe p1 and p2 are specially processed by jvm, made pointed to a single object if initialized with:

   Integer p1=0, p2=0;

If change to:

```
Integer p1=0, p2=1;
```

or

```
Integer p1 = new Integer(0);
Integer p2 = new Integer(0);
```

The result is right (p1:5, p2:10). Can anyone clarify this?

Maybe what I said is not correct. I have write the following code in java:

```
Integer a = 0;
Integer b = 0;
b = 10;
Log.d("test", "a: "+a);
Log.d("test", "b: "+b);
```

It output 0, 10. So, they point to not a single object. I'm really confused.

Comment: Don't attempt this. It will break Autoboxing and the caching of small Integer values.

Comment: Re your edit you don't appear to have read my comment above. Don't do this.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me more explanation on autoboxing on this issue? If the two Integer objects are newed, my code works. But I don't if it's a good way to pass value like that.

Comment: "Integer p1=0, p2=1;" will break too. See JLS 5.1.7 it says "If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer i1 = 500, i2 = 10000;
testInts(i1, i2);
Log.d("log", "I1 = " + i1); 
Log.d("log", "I2 = " + i2);
```

or

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(0), i2 = new Integer(0);
testInts(i1, i2);
Log.d("log", "I1 = " + i1); 
Log.d("log", "I2 = " + i2);
```

output

```
I1 = 10
I2 = 10
I1 = 5
I2 = 10
I1 = 5
I2 = 10
```

Works (first result using your example). I have remembered something that if value is in byte (or?) range then java uses some weird optimization. 
EDIT: appears it is a rule for autoboxing for small values.

c code

```
    jclass clazz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, i1);
    jfieldID mi = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, clazz, "value", "I");

    (*env)->SetIntField(env, i1, mi, 5);
    (*env)->SetIntField(env, i2, mi, 10);
    return 0;
```

Comment: I have found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature

Comment: @Deucalion what is i1 definition in 'c' code here, mean how you initialized it. Please mention.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think [Integer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html) is mutable. You’ll see it has no `set` method.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any relation between this issue with mutable object?