# Pass multiple integer value from jni to java

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I originally posted here (include the code):
[Weird: can not change the value of Integer in jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650230/weird-can-not-change-the-value-of-integer-in-jni)

To pass multiple value from jni to java, I pass 2 Integer reference to jni/c, and use SetIntField() to modify the object.

Unfortunately, the 2 value are the same. Lawrence D'Oliveiro explains Integer is not mutable, so we cant change it. I don't know why.

As a workaround, I created my own Integer class:

```
public class MyInteger {
    int value;

    public MyInteger(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

And pass object of this type to jni:

```
native int do_something(MyInteger p1, MyInteger p2);
```

It works. I'm curious why Integer doesn't work. Thanks all.

Comment: `Integer` is not mutable, yes, so what is the question exactly? If you want something mutable, use an `int[1]`

Comment: OK, it seems immutable object can't be altered. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of "immutable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has no relation with 'immutable object'. The original code using Integer doesn't work is because of autoboxing.