# how to modify the value of a primitive data passed to a C++ routine using Java and JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Can I pass a primitive from Java to my C++ function using JNI function calls and modify its value in the C++ function ?

So far, I have seen examples of returning jstring,jint,jboolean etc, which I do not want to do. The other option that I know about is to get the ID of the primitive variable within C++ and set its value.

For Example :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_myFunction
(JNIEnv *, jobject obj, jboolean retJava)
```

Here i am passing boolean from java and want to change it in C++ depending on my computation without return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can **not** do this with JNI.

You can hack it with using **boxed types** (see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650230/weird-can-not-change-the-value-of-integer-in-jni)) but it is strongly discouraged, as it can break all kinds of things easily (as to what exactly, see the comments in the linked question).

Comment: : ) Thanks - Steeve