# evaluation of expression which is used with sizeof

Tags: c, expression, sizeof

Is there any expression that would be evaluated as operand of a sizeof. I have come to know in case of variable length operand with sizeof, the expression would be evaluated. But I cant make an example,
I wrote the code below,

```
int a[]={1,2,3};
printf("%d",sizeof(a[1]++));
printf("%d\n",a[1]);
```

but here I observed from output expression `a[1]++` is not evaluating.
how to make an example??

Comment: Well, `a[1]++` isn't a variable length array, so it's not evaluated.

Comment: @DanielFischer: His confusion is why 1++ is not evaluated by `sizeof` as a 4 byte integer.

Comment: @0A0D DanielFisher's reply is correct.  `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand unless it's a variable length array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2018786#2018786

Comment: @Alok: I missed the point due to the half prose in the question.. I read it three times before it made sense now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is not a variable-length array.  A variable length array is an array whose size is not a constant expression.  For example, `data` is a variable-length array in the following:

```
int i = 10;
char data[i];
```

To see an example of a code that has `sizeof` evaluate its operand, try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 41;
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    printf("array size: %zu\n", sizeof (char[i++]));
    printf("i now: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
i: 41
array size: 41
i now: 42
```

Comment: @amin__: It says take a `char` array of size 41, increase the integer holding the size by `1` and then assign that number (`42`) to the size of the char array, which becomes `42`.

Comment: But where is that char array?? I see it is not exist. Can the char array of size 42 now be used?

Comment: @amin__: sizeof can be used with types and expressions. It's creating a temporary array for the sake of evaluating a useless variable length array because it is not used beyond that.

Comment: @Alok why dont you use data array(as it is also variable length array) instead of `char[i++]` in sizeof??

Comment: @amin__ Because you can't observe the evaluation of the expression with `data`. You need an expression with an observable side effect, the temporary `char[i++]` does just that.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I was wondering if any usable variable length array gives the observable output..anyway thank you all