# Shouldn't else be indented in the below code

Tags: python

In the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) is an example (copied below), shouldn't `else` be indented? I ran the code and it didn't work but I indented it (`else`) and it worked. Is, what I am saying right? If the documentation is wrong, then how do I report it as a bug to python doc guys?

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         if n % x == 0:
...             print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x
...             break
...     else:
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
...         print n, 'is a prime number'
...
```

Comment: Nope, because a `for` loop can have an `else` suite *as well*.

Comment: this construct made it into the 'Strangest language feature' question some time ago (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3690698/288875)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tha example is working and the indented is fine, have a look here:

```
                                                    # Ident level:
>>> for n in range(2, 10):                          # 0 
...     for x in range(2, n):                       # 1                          
...         if n % x == 0:                          # 2
...             print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x      # 3
...             break                               # 3
...     else:                                       # 1
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor                        
...         print n, 'is a prime number'            # 2
```

As you can see, the `else` relates to the second `for` by following this rule:

> Loop statements may have an else clause; **it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement**.

In the example, it means that the else will be called if the second for (in the second line) will finish running but will never run the break command - only if `n % x == 0` never eval to `TRUE`.

If `(n % x == 0)` at any point the break will be called the second for will stop, `n` from the first for will grow by 1, (n = n + 1) and the second for will be called again with a new `n`.

Answer (score 7):

See docs you linked:

```
Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop 
terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition 
becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break 
statement. This is exemplified by the following loop, which searches for 
prime numbers:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of Python's `for ... else` http://psung.blogspot.co.il/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html

It basically invokes the code in the `else` part after the for loop is over and terminated normally (not broke, in any way)