# Getting wrong answers for prime numbers

Tags: python, numbers, primes, break

I'm getting several incorrect answers in this code.  For example, 9 is showing as prime.  I'm guessing my problem is with using the breaks, but I can't seem to logically figure out what is wrong with this simple code someone asked me about.

```
for number in range(0, 1000):

    for x in range(2, number):
         if (number % x == 0):
             break
         else:
             print x
             break
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shouldn't else be indented in the below code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194947/shouldnt-else-be-indented-in-the-below-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your script, regardless of if the number is divisble by 2 or not, it breaks the loop immediately.
I've reindented the code and this is probably closer to what you were trying to do.

In your original code, if the number *is divisible by 2* (first number in the `range(2,number)`, then you break the loop and if it *is not divisible* you also break the loop. So all odd numbers, like 9, looked like primes.

The `else` keyword after a `for` loop is run *iff* the loop exits normally. So the "is prime" part will only be printed if no divisor is found.

```
for number in range(0,1000):
    for x in range(2,number):
        if(number % x == 0):
            print number,"divisible by",x
            break
    else:
        print number, "is prime"
```

You can see this is anction here: http://codepad.org/XdS413LR

Also, this is a naive algorithm (not a critique of the code, exploring simple algorithms is a useful study), but you can make a little more efficient. Technically you only need to check as far as the sqare root of `number`, as any number larger than the square root must have a complement that is less than the square root, which should have already been encountered. So the logic in the code can be changed to:

```
from math import sqrt
for number in range(0,1000):
    for x in range(2,int(sqrt(number/2))):
        # Rest of code as above.
```

That said there are many ways that you can optimise the checking or discovery of prime numbers that are worth investigating if you get the chance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and also for the very thorough explanation of what exactly was wrong with the old code.  Also for a way to make the code more efficient.

Comment: @Slimmons If you are curious, a more efficient method for prime detection that is often used in algorithms courses is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Actually you only need to check as far as sqrt(number), not number/2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
for number in xrange(100):
    for i in range(2,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            break
    else:
         print number
```

this iterates through every number form 1-100 and checks if any number is divisible by any # besides one but you need the `else:` statement out side of the inner for loop so if it goes throught the inner for loop without finding a divisor its prime

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives. First, this checks for primes:

```
def check_for_prime(n):
if n == 1: return False
elif n == 2: return True
elif n%2 == 0: return False

# Elementary prime test borrowed from oeis.org/A000040.
odds = 3
while odds < n**.5+1:
    if n%odds == 0: return False
    odds += 2
return True
```

This is slightly faster, but you should have experience using yield:

```
def primes_plus():
yield 2
yield 3
i = 5
while True:
    yield i
    if i % 6 == 1:
        i += 2
    i += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here are some alternatives.**

n is the number till the range you want to find

```
n=100
for i in range(0,n):
    num = filter(lambda y :i % y == 0,(y for y in range(2,(i/2))))
    if num or i == 4:
        print "%s not a prime number" %(i)
    else:
        print "%s is a prime number" %(i)
```