# integer indexed with a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, indexing, integer, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

How is it possible that this is valid C++?

```
void main()
{
  int x = 1["WTF?"];
}
```

On VC++10 this compiles and in debug mode the value of `x` is 84 after the statement.

What's going on?

Comment: This must be a duplicate of a few dozen questions...

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995156/238902)

Comment: A better question is for some user defined types that overload the `operator [](int)` would this work: `5[myType()]`

Comment: sorry for duplicate question, didn't know what to search for

Comment: @paul23 the intrinsic scalers are short-cut by the compiler. So not directly. However... never say never. Check out [this useless piece of code](http://ideone.com/bYrlXf) which has a cast-operator for `int*`. It does exactly what you think it might. Good times.

Comment: @WhoizCraig That's awesome, hehe.

Comment: I sometimes to this with index variables just to see the double take on peer-programmers faces. you know, a complicated for-loop and buried in the middle of it: `i++[arName]` and such. Keeps them on their toes =P

Answer (score 9):

Array subscript operator is commutative. It's equivalent to `int x = "WTF?"[1];` Here, `"WTF?"` is an array of 5 `char`s (it includes null terminator), and `[1]` gives us the second char, which is `'T'` - implicitly converted to `int` it gives value 84.

Offtopic: The code snippet isn't valid C++, actually - `main` must return `int`.

You can read more in-depth discussion here: [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Comment: +1 for the *main must return int* :)

Comment: ok it's valid Microsoft C++ in that it compiles :)

Comment: I'm surprised that it doesn't also grab the letters after it and give you `0x003F4654`, since you declared the variable `x` as an `int` rather than a `char`

Answer (score 3):

```
int x = 1["WTF?"];
```

equals to

```
int x = "WTF?"[1];
```

84 is "T" ascii code

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this works is that when the built-in operator `[]` is applied to a pointer and an int, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`. Which (addition being commutative) is equivalent to `*(b+a)`, which, by definition of `[]`, is equivalent to `b[a]`.