# Why does the expression X["Y"] behave as "Y"[X]?

Tags: c++, string

Consider the below syntax :

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << 1["ABC"] << std::endl;
}
```

The program outputs `B` which leads me to believe that it behaves as `"ABC"[1]`. Is that possible, what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: This is tagged C, but also work for C++.

Comment: This is how C has been designed more than 40 years ago; C++ inherited this behaviour.

Comment: Somewhat coincidentally, it's ultimately because of [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)).

Comment: Don't really understand the downvote. This is well posed and isn't exactly obvious nor intuitve.

Comment: @PasserBy Because it's a duplicate.

Comment: @user202729 You don't downvote because of duplicates.

Comment: @PasserBy [Sometimes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334361/downvote-duplicate-question).

Comment: @Bathsheba [We had enough duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/381542?page=1&sort=hot).

Comment: @Bathsheba [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378650/integer-indexed-with-a-string-in-c) directly use string literal.

Comment: @user202729: Touche. If I reopen, could someone close to that? (I can't do it if I've voted to reopen).

Comment: @user202729 I tried some simple queries, the duplicates aren't easy to find unless you already know what you're looking for.

Comment: Can someone close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378650/integer-indexed-with-a-string-in-c please?

Comment: @Bathsheba Why not yourself...

Comment: @liliscent: Wow, didn't know I could hammer reopen then hammer close. I'll take steps to ensure the power doesn't go to my head. I know this dupe target is C, but the langages are similar in this respect. Note though that "ABC" is a `char[4]` literal in C but a `const char[4]` literal in C++,