# How can the output be explained?

Tags: c, pointers

I am dealing pointers in c and when i run the following code i get "l" as the output! Why?

```
char *s = "Hello, World!";
 printf("%c", 2[s]);
```

What does 2[s] signify?

Comment: because `2[s] == s[2]`

Comment: duplicate of this classic http://stackoverflow.com/a/1995156/297323

Comment: You have 6 answers that are the same. Choose one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This prints **s[2]** which is l. It's because **s[i]** is a syntactically equal to ***(s + i)**. Therefore **s[2]** and **2[s**] are *both converted* to ***(s + 2).**

Answer (score 7):

`2[s]` is same as `s[2]` because compiler convert both into `*(2 + s)`

here is a good link for you: [why are both index[array] and array[index] valid in C?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146951/why-are-both-indexarray-and-arrayindex-valid-in-c)

Comment: Also note that it would not work for an arrays of larger types. since `s[2]` is actually `*(s+2*sizeof(char))`. If `s` was an array of integers, `2[s]` was still `*(2+s)`, but `s[2]` was `*(s*sizeof(int))`, which is equal to `8[s]`(assuming `sizeof(int)==4`).

Comment: @IdanArye that's wrong. The expression `s+2` is always identical to `2+s`. Pointer arithmetic always works on multiples of the pointed-to type.

Comment: @IdanArye That's interesting but I don't think it's right. Where did you read it?

Comment: I stand corrected. I forgot that int is cast to the pointer type, not visa versa

Answer (score 3):

both s[2] and 2[s] are same. This is how the C compiler is built.
Internally s[2] is treated as *(s+2). which is similar to 2[s].

Answer (score 2):

2[s] is same as s[2] which could be written as *(s+2).

Answer (score 0):

It is another way of writing `s[2]`, they mean the same thing. In this case, it would print the 3rd character of your string, which is an 'l'